# A call to a static method within the parameter list of super() is valid in Java. Why?

Tags: java, static

Let's look at the following code snippet in Java.

```
package trickyjava;

class A
{
    public A(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

final class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        super(method());      // Calling the following method first.      
    }

    private static String method()
    {
        return "method invoked";
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

---

By convention, the **super()** constructor in Java must be the first statement in the relevant constructor body. In the above code, we are calling the **static** method in the super() constructor parameter list itself **super(method());**.

---

It means that in the call to super in the constructor **B()**, a method is being
called BEFORE the call to super is made! This should be forbidden by the compiler but it works nice. This is somewhat equivalent to the following statements.

```
String s = method();
super(s);
```

However, it's illegal causing a compile-time error indicating that "call to super must be  first statement in constructor". Why? and why it's equivalent **super(method());**  is valid and the compiler doesn't complain any more?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-does-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor

Comment: `super` IS the first statement in the constructor, despite not being called first. The specification state that `The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit invocation of another constructor ...`, not that it must be called first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key thing here is the `static` modifier. Static methods are tied to the *class*, instance methods (normal methods) are tied to an *object* (class instance). The constructor initializes an object from a class, therefore the class must already have been fully loaded. It is therefore no problem to call a static method as part of the constructor.

The sequence of events to load a class and create an object is like this:

1. load class
2. initialize static variables
3. create object
4. initialize object <-- with constructor
5. object is now ready for use

(simplified*)

By the time the object constructor is called, the static methods and variables are available.

Think of the class and its `static` members as a blueprint for the objects of that class. You can only create the objects when the blueprint is already there.

The constructor is also called the initializer. If you throw an exception from a constructor and print the stack trace, you'll notice it's called `<init>` in the stack frame. Instance methods can only be called after an object has been constructed. It is not possible to use an instance method as the parameter for the `super(...)` call in your constructor.

If you create multiple objects of the same class, steps 1 and 2 happen only once.

(*static initializers and instance initializers left out for clarity)

Comment: Actually, you could call an instance method of another class, or even this one, if you got the instance from somewhere else (eg, a static method or a public static field, or a parameter to the init method).  You just can't use "this".

Answer (score 5):

Yep, checking the JVM spec (though admittedly an old one):

In the instance init method, no reference to "this" (including the implicit reference of a return) may occur before a call to either another init method in the same class or an init method in the superclass has occurred.

This is really the only real restriction, so far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

The aim of requiring the super constructor to be invoked first is to ensure that the "super object" is fully initialized before it is used (It falls short of actually enforcing this because the super constructor can leak `this`, but that's another matter).

Calling a non-static method on `this` would allow the method to see uninitialized fields and is therefore forbidden. A static method can only see these fields if it is passed `this` as argument. Since accessing `this` and `super` is illegal in super constructor invocation expressions, and the call to super happens before the declaration of any variables that might point to `this`, allowing calls to static methods in super constructor invocation expressions is safe.

It is also useful, because it allows to compute the arguments to the super constructor in an arbitrarily complex manner. If calls to static methods weren't allowed, it would be impossible to use control flow statements in such a computation. Something as simple as:

```
class Sub extends Super {
    Sub(Integer... ints) {
        super(Arrays.asList(ints));
    }
}
```

would be impossible.

Answer (score 3):

This is one situation where the java syntax hides what's really going on, and C# makes it a bit clearer.

In C# your B would look like

```
class B : A {
    public B() : base(method()) {
    }

    private static String method() {
        return "method invoker";
    }
}
```

Although the java syntax places `super(method)` within the constructor it's not really called there: All the parent initialization is run **before** your subclass constructor. The C# code shows this a little more clearly; by placing `super(method())` at the first line of the java constructor you're simply telling java to use the parameterized constructor of the super class rather than the parameterless version; this way you can pass variables to the parent constructor and they'll be used in the initialization of the parent level fields **before** your child's constructor code runs.

The reason that `super(method())` is valid (as the first line in a java constructor) is because `method()` is being loaded with the static elements--before the non-static ones, including the constructors--which allows it to be called not only before `B()`, but before `A(String)` as well. By saying

```
public B() {
   String s = method();
   super(s);
}
```

you're telling the java compiler to initialize the super object with the default constructor (because the call to `super()` isn't the first line) and you're ready to initialize the subclass, but the compiler then becomes confused when it sees that you're trying to initialize with `super(String)` after `super()` has already run.

Answer (score 2):

A call to super is a must in java to allow the parent to get initalized before anything with child class starts.

In the case above, if java allows `String s= method();` before the call to super, it opens up flood gate of things that can be done before a call to super. that would risk so many things, essentially that allows a half baked class to be used. Which is rightly not allowed. It would allow things like object state (some of which may belong to the parent) being modified before it was properly created.

In case of `super(method());` call, we still adhere to the policy of completing parent initialization before child. and we can use a static member only, and static member of child classes are available before any child objects are created anyways. so the method is avilable and can be called.

Answer (score 0):

OK..i think, this one could be relevant that, **if we are calling some member with Super, then it first try to invoke in super class and if it doesn't find same one then it'll try to invoke the same in subclass.**

PS: correct me if i'm wrong