# How it works parent class constructor called from subclass without using super keyword in java

Tags: java

i want to call super class constructor in sub class construtor. For that i am using super() but without super() also, i can able to call super class constructor. how it works.

1. Example: here i am using super()
   [image]

2.Example: here i am not using super(), but it works fine

[image]

Comment: how it called the parent class constructor without super()......any idea?

Comment: see the already existing question and answer. Also it is recommended to include code as text and not screenshots...

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508107/why-call-super-in-a-constructor)

Comment: ok...It may be duplicate,But I need to know why the parent class constructor called without super() ?

Comment: @KarthickA.S It is called because the [Java Language Specification (section 8.8.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) says so (_"If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments."_)