# Why do an Adapter need a super Method?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am working with ArrayAdapters. I am a bit troubled to understand why a super method (not sure if its a keyword or method in this case?) is applied and introduced. Also, why is its middle constructor value 0?

Cheers.

```
public class AttractionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Attraction> {

public AttractionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Attraction> attractions) {
    super(context, 0, attractions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a requirement of `ArrayAdapter`s. That is simply *Java*: [Why call super() in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508107/why-call-super-in-a-constructor)

You **must** call `super` in the constructor of a derived class if the parent class does not have a constructor without parameters (otherwise the call is implicit and you can avoid to call `super()`). [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-67/) some details.

Just for testing, try to extend `BaseAdapter`. It's constructor does not have parameters -> it is not necessary to call `super()` (actually it is called, but you don't need to write it).

Answer (score 0):

That is the constructor of the ArrayAdapter, with wchich you create a new AttractionAdapter. You don't need to call super there most of the time. You can look up what super does in the Java 7 documentation. Also, the 0 is where your item goes. The item which the adapter is going to "copy and paste" to create a list. For now, the adapter has no items to display.