# why does this code give error as actual formal parameter?

Tags: java

```
 class A {
    int a, b;

    A(int i, int j) {
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int c, d;

    B(int i, int j) {
        c = i;
        d = j;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aa = new A(5, 6);
        B bb = new B(3, 4);
        System.out.println(aa.a + aa.b + bb.a + bb.b + bb.c + bb.d);

    }
}
```

it gives error as

```
HelloWorld.java:9: error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                    
^                                                                                                                                                                    
  required: int,int                                                                                                                                                  
  found: no arguments                                                                                                                                                
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length                                                                                                          
1 error
```

Comment: The constructor in B calls the no-argument constructor in A .... which you don't have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why call super() in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508107/why-call-super-in-a-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

As you class `B` **extends** class `A`, you somewhere have to call the constructor of the class you are extending.

---

As your class `A` does not have a constructor with **no arguments**, you need to explicitly call the super constructor (the constructor from class `A`) as the first statement inside the constructor of your class `B`:

```
B(int i, int j) {
  super(i, j);
  // Your code
}
```

---

If you would have a no-args constructor in `A`, you would not need to do this, as the **no-args constructor is implicitly** called if no constructor call is specified:

```
B(int i, int j) {
  // Your code
}
```

Is actually doing:

```
B() {
  super();
  // Your code
}
```

And as you do not have `A()` as a constructor, you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one...
JVM always looking for no argument constructor.

```
class A {
    int a, b;

    A(int i, int j) {
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }

    public A() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int c, d;

    B(int i, int j) {
        c = i;
        d = j;
    }
}

public class pivot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aa = new A(5, 6);
        B bb = new B(3, 4);
        System.out.println(aa.a + aa.b + bb.a + bb.b + bb.c + bb.d);

    }
}
```