# What is the reason for PMD CallSuperInConstructor?

Tags: java, constructor, super, pmd

PMD defines the rule [CallSuperInConstructor](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.10.0/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#callsuperinconstructor).  What is the purpose of adding a no-argument call to `super()` in the constructor when it is not required by the compiler?

I realize I could disable the rule or use `@SuppressWarnings` to silence the rule in each class.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508107/why-call-super-in-a-constructor) deals with why one should call `super(...)` in a constructor.  My question is about why one would add a no-argument `super()` call when the compiler does not require it.

Comment: Short answer is if you are extending anything other than Object, you want to give your parent object a chance to do any special initialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why call super() in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508107/why-call-super-in-a-constructor)

Comment: @JustinKSU The Java compiler will automatically add a call to the superclass constructor if there is no explicit call in the code, so your explanation makes no sense. Your duplicate also doesn't answer the question why PMD defines this rule.

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate of "Why call super() in a constructor?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class

- has numerous overloaded constructors
- is extending a non-`Object` class which has numerous overloaded constructors

then when you explicitly call `super()` it avoids confusion which class/superclass constructor is called.

An example illustrating the above:

```
class Foo {
    final int x;
    Foo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    Foo() {
        this.x = 1;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    Bar(int x) {
    }
}
```

Question - what is the value of `new Bar(10).x`?