# Why don't subclasses inherit constructors?

Tags: inheritance, constructor

I'm brand new to Java and we're learning about inheritance and subclasses. In the text and online it is said that subclasses do not inherit constructors from their respective superclasses; however in a quiz question we were asked the output of the following code;

```
class Food {
    Food() { printFlavor(); }
    void printFlavor() { System.out.println("bland"); }
}
class Pepper extends Food {
    void printFlavor() { System.out.println("spicy"); }
}
public class Lunch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food lunch = new Pepper();
    }
}
```

I assumed that since constructors are not inherited that the output should be nothing; because the compiler would use the default constructor for Pepper; however this was incorrect. Am I missing something glaringly obvious? Running it myself I can see that it uses the constructor for Food, since it calls the printFlavor subroutine, but I can't understand why if subclasses don't inherit constructors.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508202/6512857

Comment: @Will This did help, actually, thank you! I had been getting the feeling that it was some sort of implicit call but hadn't seen anything that would point that out so wasn't sure. Thanks a lot!