# Empty Feign configuration is not extended

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have several Feign clients, with different configurations. The common config looks like the following

```
public class FeignLogConfig {
    @Bean
    public LogOkHttpInterceptor LogOkHttpInterceptor() { //custom interceptor
        return new LogOkHttpInterceptor(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient okHttpClient(LogOkHttpInterceptor interceptor) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        return new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(builder.build());
    }
}
```

that can be further extended

```
public class FeignRetryerConfig extends FeignLogConfig {
    @Bean
    public Retryer retryer() {
        return new Retryer.Default(100, 500, 5);
    }
}
```

or simply

```
public class FeignEmptyConfig extends FeignLogConfig {}
```

A client annotated with

```
@FeignClient(value = "retryClient", url = url, configuration = FeignRetryerConfig.class)
```

or

```
@FeignClient(value = "logClient", url = url, configuration = FeignLogConfig.class)
```

will actually use the defined interceptor, yet

```
@FeignClient(value = "emptyClient", url = url, configuration = FeignEmptyConfig.class)
```

would not use the `LogOkHttpInterceptor`. I can't find an explanation on the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html), so I don't know if I'm actually missing something.

A minimal example can be found [here](https://github.com/dcolazin/reprexes/tree/main/SO_73742384).

EDIT: to me, at the moment, seems not related to Feign, but to how Spring aggregates the configurations. While the above `FeignEmptyConfig` doesn't work, the following does work!

```
@Import(CommonFeignConfig.class)
public class EmptyFeignConfig {}
```

Comment: Can you show your configuration class and your feign interface please ?

Comment: Maybe you just need to set a constructor in the FeignEmptyConfig.

Comment: @Zabon I added a repository where I replicate the issue; what constructor should I set in the empty config?

Comment: If your class extends another you have to add the super inside your constructor. But since your class doesn't have any properties, only beans, I'm not sure of what I'm saying.

Comment: @Zabon there is a implicit super() call anyway https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508202/11478354