# Trying to make a parent class

Tags: java

I have 2 classes, `cPuzzlePieces` and `cShapes`. `cPuzzlePieces` extends `cShapes`.

Right now I get 2 errors on `cPuzzlePeaces`.

The first error is on the first line of the def and says:

```
implacet super constructor cShapes is undefined for default constructor.
```

The second error on the first line of the construter says

```
constructor call must be the first staemnt
```

and it is on the first staement.

Here is my code:

```
public class cPuzzlePieces extends cShapes{ // first error message is here

    int mAmountOfShapes;
    Context InContext;

    void cPuzzlePieces(Context MyContext) throws IOException 
    {
        super( MyContext);  // SECOND ERROR MESSAGE IS HERE
        InContext=MyContext;
    }
}




public class cShapes 
{
    cShape[] MyShapes;
public int mAmountOfShapes=0;
boolean AnimationRunning=false;

cShapes(Context InContext) throws IOException
{

}

...
...
}
```

Comment: Class names start with an uppercase letter. Make sure you copy errors exactly, without typos.

Comment: Your class names shouldn't start with a lowercase `c`. They should just be `PuzzlePieces` and `Shapes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
void cPuzzlePieces(Context MyContext) throws IOException
```

is a method, not a constructor.

Remove the `void` keyword. Add an appropriate access modifier (if need be). Also check for the `IOException`. Currently, nothing is throwing it.

Related

- ["Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor" issue in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072534/constructor-call-must-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor-issue-in-java)

---

Java naming conventions state that class names should start with an uppercase alphanumeric character. Please follow that.