# How to run a function before calling super in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I have a constructor which gets a HashSet and a HashMap. I need to run a validation check on one hashMAp  and combine it with the hashSet, as 'super' must receive only one hashSet.
I can't find a way to do it as I get following error: `cannot reference this before supertype constructor`

Example:

```
public class A extends B {
  public A(HashSet<Obj> h1, HashMap<UID,Objects> m1) {
    super(new C (h1) ); //h1 should contain changes related to m1..
}
```

I want to do something like that:

```
public class A extends B {
      public A(HashSet<Obj> h1, HashMap<UID,Objects> m1) {
        runMyFunc(h1,m1);
        super(new C (h1) );
    }



 runMyFunc(HashSet<Obj> h1, HashMap<UID,Objects> m1){
      //do checks
      //more checks...
      // if something then h1.setUid(m1.get(0))... 
      return h1;
   }
```

I thought converting the constructor to private and then run it like that:

```
public class A extends B {
  private A(HashSet<Obj> h1) {
    super(new C (h1) ); 
}

 public A(HashSet<Obj> h1, HashMap<UID,Objects> m1) {
     runMyFunc(h1,m1);
     this(h1);
 }
```

but it also didn't work.

Can you please advice?

Comment: Can't you simply set a `super`'s field at the end of `A`'s constructor calls?

Comment: A call to `super()` or `this()` must be the first line in a constructor.  `super()` is called automatically (with no arguments) if you don't insert it yourself.

You can get around the problem by using a factory method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your method  `static` and make sure it returns your new `h1`.

```
public static HashSet<Obj> runMyFunc(HashSet<Obj> h1, HashMap<UID,Objects> m1) {
     // Some mutation to h1
     return h1;
}
```

Use it in the first line as follows:

```
this(runMyFunc(h1,m1));
```

### But why?

You must be wondering *"Why am I able to use static methods and not instance methods?"*. Well, before you can call your methods, your parent's object has to be instantiated first, this is meant to help the compiler prevent you from accessing attributes/methods/whatever that are not yet available. Static methods are safe cause by definition can't access any of that.

### Related posts

- [Why does this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-does-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor)
- [Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072534/constructor-call-must-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor-issue-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You should be able to format on mobile as well. Anyway.. done

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin - If you are using a device that doesn't allow you to format answers, you shouldn't be posting answers!

Comment: @StephenC this is being discussed on meta - > http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342484/should-you-refrain-from-answering-if-you-cant-format-an-answer?cb=1

Comment: @CalvT I think it's this question indeed.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin I'm pretty sure it is as the OP on meta edited the other answer - that's how I tracked this one down ;)

Answer (score 6):

Just make your `runMyFunc` **static**, and invoke it as a function where you use the return value in the `super` invocation. That is allowed:

```
public class A extends B {
  public A(HashSet<Obj> h1, HashMap<UID,Objects> m1) {
     // Invoke as function rather than by itself on a separate line
     super(new C (runMyFunc(h1,m1)) );
  }

  // Make method static
  public static HashSet<Obj> runMyFunc(HashSet<Obj> h1, HashMap<UID,Objects> m1) {
     //do checks
     //more checks...
     // if something then h1.setUid(m1.get(0))... 
     return h1;
  }
```