# How to simplify similar constructors?

Tags: java

How can I simplify this:

Is it necessary to have two different constructors with just one little difference.

Is there a way to simplify that using just one of them?

```
public class MyCostructor {

    public MyCostructor(int w, int h, String name) {
         this.w = w;
         this.h = h;
         this.name = name;
    }
    
    public MyCostructor(int w, int h) {
         this.w = w;
         this.h = h;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can use the keyword `this` to call another constructor and you respect the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself).

```
public MyCostructor(int w, int h){ 
   this(w,h,null);
}
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) (section Using this with a Constructor)

Answer (score 3):

Use `this()` in your constructor:

```
public MyCostructor(int w, int h, String name) {
    this(w, h);
    this.name = name;
}

public MyCostructor(int w, int h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}
```

Comment: usual practice is to call `this()` from constructor with less arguments

Comment: @Lashane yes, but in this case there's no need to set `this.name = null;` since that's the default value. Besides, IMO sending `null` as parameter is not quite right (even if it does the right job), do you?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza so you mean it is not possible to do everything with only one constructor, right? I mean.. **in a game** I want to create a car with a yellow dot in the front and another equal car without the dot, two constructors are necessary in that case?

Comment: @user3569452 sadly, yes. You can only simplify the way you implement the constructors using `this()` as the first line of the constructor.

Comment: @user3569452 it is depends on your class structure, you can define "dot" as optional attribute and just provide getters/setters for it, also take look at builders and chaining http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171012/how-to-avoid-constructor-code-redundancy-in-java