# Is there an easier way to write lots of constructors with different signatures?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I'm creating a class called `Location` that has 7 instance variables, such as `street`, `suburb`, `city`, etc.

While I was creating all the different constructors with different signatures (including the default constructor), I started thinking that there must be an easier way to go about doing this. If I had a class with 15 or so instance variables, I could spend all day typing out the possibilities.

Am I right in thinking that there is an easier method?

Comment: Check out [the Builder Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) or [chain the constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171012/how-to-avoid-constructor-code-redundancy-in-java).