# Keyword 'this' with parenthesis that receive parameters in Java 'this(param1,param2)'. Can it be used in setters?

Tags: java, constructor, this, setter

Java allows to summarize `this.classVar = parameter; this.classVar2 = parameter2;`  expressions to `this(parameter, parameter2)`. At least used in a constructor.
But this code doesn't work when I change from the former way (commented in the code) to the latter way in a setter:

```
class Client {
    String nombre, apellidos, residencia;
    double comision;
    void setClient(String nombre, String apellidos, String residencia, double comision){
        this(nombre, apellidos, residencia, comision);
        //this.nombre = nombre;
        //this.apellidos = apellidos;
        //this.residencia = residencia;
        //this.comision = comision; 
    }
}
```

Error says:

```
"call to this must be first statement in the constructor. 

Constructor in class Client cannot be applied to given types.

required: no arguments
<p>found: String, String, String, double
<p>reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length" (I haven't created one, just left the default).
```

So, is this way of using '`this`' only valid for constructors, and therefore not suitable for setters? Does it require to explicitly code the constructor (if so, why?)?

Comment: You are calling the constructor with the argument list: `String, String, String, double`. There is no such constructor. Also you can't call a constructor like that from within a method.

Comment: Yes. `this` is only for calling a constructor from a different one. You do need to code it otherwise you can't call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Java allows to summarize `this.classVar = parameter; this.classVar2 = parameter2;` expressions to `this(parameter, parameter2)`.

No, it doesn't. You still have to code the `this.classVar = parameter; this.classVar2 = parameter2;` somewhere. All `this(parameter, parameter2)` does is call a constructor (which would have to have the `this.classVar = parameter; this.classVar2 = parameter2;` code in it, if those parameters were going to be written to those fields).

You can't call the constructor from a setter. You can only call a constructor from within a constructor. It's used to consolidate logic in a single constructor even when you have more than one with varying parameters, for example:

```
public MyContainer(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}
public MyContainer() {
    this(16);
}
```

There, the zero-parameters version of the `MyContainer` constructor calls the single-parameter version, passing it `16` for the `size` parameter.

Comment: just adding a bit: the 'Explicit Cnstructor Invocation' like `this(...)` must be the the first statement of an(other) constructor

Answer (score 2):

`this(nombre, apellidos, residencia, comision)` doesn't "summarize" anything.

It's just a way to call another constructor in the class from a constructor.

There is no way to "summarize" anything

Answer (score 1):

```
this(/* zero or more args */);
```

This is a constructor call. You can use it from one constructor to refer to another (for lack of a better name, '[constructor chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171012/how-to-avoid-constructor-code-redundancy-in-java)').

You cannot do the same thing from a normal method. If you want to create an object from within a normal method, you use the same syntax as you'd use an an external user of the class:

```
new MyClass(/* args */);
```

From your code, it doesn't look like this is the approach you'd want to take.