# Why can't I add extra argument validation in the subclass constructor?

Tags: java, validation, constructor, abstract, superclass

I have two classes. The superclass:

```
public abstract class Question(){

public Question(String question, String answer, String... alts){...
}
```

And the subclass:

```
public class StringOptionsQuestion extends Question {

public StringOptionsQuestion(String question, String answer, String... alts){
    if (alts.length == 0){throw new IllegalArgumentException();} //The compiler doesn't like this line.
    super(question, answer, alts);
}}
```

I want my subclass, `StringOptionsQuestion`, to validate the length of `alts` before it passes it on to the superclass' constructor. However, I can't do it this way. I get the error "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor". Why does this error exist? And how can I bypass it in my case?

Comment: **No** you have to call the `super(...)` first before you can do anything

Comment: i suggest you look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-does-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor

Comment: @Blip: Not before you can do *anything* - see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As kocko notes, the `super` statement must be the first *statement* in your constructor. However, if you really, really don't want to get as far as the superconstructor before validating (e.g. because it will blow up with a less-helpful error), you can validate while evaluating the arguments to the superconstructor:

```
public class StringOptionsQuestion extends Question {

    public StringOptionsQuestion(String question, String answer, String... alts) {
        super(question, answer, validateAlternatives(alts));
    }

    private static String[] validateAlternatives(String[] alternatives) {
        if (alternatives.length == 0) { 
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return alternatives;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you answered perfectly.

Comment: Hi Jon, this code doesn't compile - you are not returning anything in the `validateAlternatives` method.

Answer (score 3):

The `super()` statement **must** be the first one in your constructor:

```
super(question, answer, alts);
if (alts.length == 0) { 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the OP's request to validate the length before it passes it onto the superclass constructor. Most of the time this approach is fine, but sometimes you really do want to validate first - and you can, in many cases, as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the call to `super(...)` *must* be the first statement in a subclass constructor.

However, it doesn't have to be the first *expression* that is being evaluated.

If you *really* need to do something before you call the superclass constructor (and this is not standard code - you should really document why you are doing this if you are) then you can do something like this, by calling a static method as an expression:

```
public class StringOptionsQuestion extends Question {

    private static String[] checkAlts(String[] alts) {
        if (alts.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return alts;
    }

    public StringOptionsQuestion(String question, String answer, String... alts) {
        super(question, answer, checkAlts(alts));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Super class constructor will be always called. Either you explicitly calls it or java does it for you. And when you do it explicitly from your subclass constructor it has to be the first thing in your constructor.

I am not sure what exactly is your requirement, but my guess is you want to avoid constructing the object in the case of your StringOptionsQuestion subclass if alts.length == 0. You can achieve this by adding another constructor in your super class which takes an extra boolean parameter say 'checkLength' and if its value is true  validate for length and throw the exception if needed. Then from your StringOptionsQuestion subclass call the new constructor.

public abstract class Question(){

public Question(String question, String answer, String... alts){...
}

public Question(String question, String answer, String... alts, boolean checkLength){

if (checkLength && alts.length == 0){throw new IllegalArgumentException();}

}

}

public class StringOptionsQuestion extends Question {

public StringOptionsQuestion(String question, String answer, String... alts){

```
super(question, answer, alts, true);
```

}}