# Why call to " this " must be first statement in constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, this

I am trying to execute this below code sample to understand why call to " this "  must be first statement in constructor ?? I had read lot of About it and I understand Why this is so !!

so I write the below simple program But Still showing me the same Error even I use 'this' as a First Statement in my Program .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Demo
{
    int x=23;

    Demo()
    {
        this(55);
    }

    Demo(int x)
    {
        this.x=x;
        System.out.println("Inside Parameterise Constructor 2"+"\n Value of x:"+x);     
    }
    
}

class ThisDemo
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Demo obj = new Demo();
    }
}
```

Comment: `void Demo()` - that isn't declaring a constructor... it's declaring a void method.

Comment: got it !! silly mistake .. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

To specifically answer your question, this or super needs to be the first call to ensure the base class has been setup correctly.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1168356/154186

To solve your error above, remove the void type from the function call. e.g.:

```
Demo(int x) {
  this.x = x;
}
Demo() {
  this(50);
}
```

Comment: got it !! silly mistake .. thanks :)

Comment: This does not not answer the question, even the link to the other topic. It only explains the super()

Answer (score 1):

Remove void from Demo constructors

```
class Demo
{
    int x=23;

    Demo()
    {
        this(55);
    }
    Demo(int x)
    {
        this.x=x;
        System.out.println("Inside Parameterise Constructor 2"+"\n Value of x:"+x);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect .. thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove void.Constructor must have no explicit return type.
Then it will work fine.

Comment: Yup !! its working .. thanks for reply .