# How to handle additional cases in subclass constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have a java class.

```
Class ClassA {
    ClassA(int type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1: handleType1(); break;
            case 2: handleType2(); break;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(); break;
        }
    }

    private void handleType1(){}
    private void handleType2(){}
}
```

Now I have to add support for type 3 and type 4. But I can not modify code of ClassA.

So I thought I would write ClassB which extends ClassA and add support for type3 and type 4 as below.

```
Class ClassB extends ClassA{
    ClassB(int type)
    {
        case 3: handleType3(); break;
        case 4: handleType4(); break;
        default:
        {
            try{
                /* To support type 1 and type 2. */
                super(type);
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
              /* Handle exception. */
            }
        } break;
    }

    private void handleType3(){}
    private void handleType4(){}
}
```

I thought this would work. But I got "**Call to super() must be first statement in constructor body**" error in ClassB's construcor.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-does-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor) and I understand why super() has to be the first statement in the constructor.

I can address my use-case by writing complete code of ClassA in ClassB and adding support for type 3 and 4. But I want to know if there are any better solutions to this problem.

Comment: I think there is a problem with app architecture when it comes to such doubts...

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have to add support for type 3 and type 4. But I can not modify code of ClassA.

Then `ClassB` **cannot** reasonably subclass `ClassA`. A subclass must call a parent class constructor. (The *unreasonable* way it might subclass it would be to lie to the `ClassA` constructor by passing in a different type.)

Ideally, `ClassA` and `ClassB` would both implement an interface, and the rest of the application would be coded to use that interface rather than `ClassA` or `ClassB` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Parent class **must** be correctly initialized (via explicitly or implicitly calling parent class constructor) during initializing a child class, but in your case parent class can't be initialized with types 3 and 4 (and without types too).

Answer (score 0):

You have a serious design flaw.

switches in general are a strong sign that you should make use of *interfaces* and *polymorphism*.

The code you currently have in the constructor of `A` should be in a *factory* class, and there should be an implementation of an interface declaring common methods for each `handleTypeX`