# Constructor is giving 2 errors

Tags: java

```
package vehicleapp;

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    int seatCap;

    public Car(String name, int modelNo, int seatCap) {
        this.seatCap = seatCap;
        super(name, modelNo);
    }
}
```

What's the problem in this code?

Comment: please mark an answer to this if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

`super(name, modelNo);` must be the first statement in the constructor body (whenever you include it explicitly), since the super class constructor must be executed prior to the body of the sub-class constructor :

```
public Car(String name, int modelNo, int seatCap) {
    super(name, modelNo);
    this.seatCap = seatCap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In any constructor call, *super* must be the first line if it is being used. [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

```
super(name, modelNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `super()` as the first line inside your constructor for the reason as shared in an SO-answer here - [why-does-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1168356/1746118) and you can change your existing code as -

```
public Car(String name, int modelNo, int seatCap) {
    super(name, modelNo);
    this.seatCap = seatCap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **Vehicleapp** package

Your vehicle class must be like this

```
public class Vehicle{
private String name,modelNo;
    Vehicle(String name ,String modelNo)
    {
          this.name=name;
          this.modelNo=modelNo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Super(); keyword should be in the top as you are creating a constructor in the child class, the constructor first looks for the superClass constructor and till the Object SuperClass.

Hirearchy:

child Contrctor-> (looks for parent Constructor) ->ParentClass ->(If it is also inheriting for any superClass it should have superclass's superClass constructor i.e Super();) ->... ->Object SuperClass.

Usually we have the keyword super(); in all the user defined Constructor, but being obvious its not written.