# Why is this returning a null arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, construct

I want to create two constructors, one that creates a `Human` with an `age` and a `name`, and one that uses the first constructor to create a human with a **random** age and name.

I create an array of names `[Name1, Name2,...,Name9]` and pick out a random name, then I create a random age between 1-100 and store it as `rage`, finally I create a `Human` with its random `name` and `age`.

In my main method, I want to create an arraylist of 9 random Humans and print it out, but I just get 9 Humans with name: `null` and age: 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class Human {
    int age;
    String name;

    public Human (int myAge, String myName) {
        name = myName;
        age = myAge;
    }

    public Human() {
        ArrayList<String> randomnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j=1;j<10;j++) {
            randomnames.add("Namn"+j);
        }
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomnames.size());
        String rname = randomnames.get(index); 

        int rage = (int) (Math.random()*100)

        Human randomPerson = new Human(rage,rname);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Object> randomHumans = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (int j=1;j<10;j++) {
                Human randomPerson = new Human();
                randomHumans.add(randomPerson);
            }
        System.out.println(randomHumans);
    }
}
```

Comment: format your code, please

Comment: What do you mean by "returning a null arraylist"?

Comment: @Pshemo; it's returning an arraylist with 9 objects that has name: null and age: 0

Comment: The attributes of the object are not set. The arraylist is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to write `this(rage,rname)` but this only works if it's the first line in the constructor. To make it the first line in the constructor, two functions need to be created first.

```
private int randomAge(){
    return randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
}

private String randomName(){
    return "Namn"+randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
}
```

After these two functions are created, the second constructor can say `this(randomAge(),randomName())`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Human()` constructor, you wrote

```
Human randomPerson = new Human(rage,rname);
```

This does not initialize your `Human`, instead it creates another object.

The proper way of doing it is:

```
this(rage,rname); // Invoke Human(int, String) constructor
```

Because this() must be the first line, you can write helper methods like:

```
private static int randomAge(){
    return (int) (Math.random()*100);
}

private static String randomName(){
    ArrayList<String> randomnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j=1;j<10;j++) {
        randomnames.add("Namn"+j);
    }
    return randomnames.get((int)(Math.random()*randomnames.size())); 
}
```

Then your constructor will just simply be

```
public Human(){
    this(randomAge(),randomName());
}
```

Notice that `randomAge()` and `randomName()` must be declared `static` because you can't invoke non-static methods before the call to `this()` because the object doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's saying that a constructor call has to be the first statement in my Human()-constructor, but that won't work for me because I only create rage and rname at the end of my Human()-constructor, so I can't write this(rage,rname); as my first line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor

Comment: The first part of this is correct. However, `this(rage, rname)` is not correct, as you have to put that first, where the properties are dynamically created.

Comment: You can generate the ArrayList and store it as a `static` variable in your class. Then you can do a nice little trick to fit everything in one line like this: `this((int)Math.random()*100,new Random().nextInt(randomnames.size()))`. Alternatively you can write helper methods `getRandomAge()` and `getRandomName()` and do `this(getRandomAge(),getRandomName())`

Comment: You might want to display that in your question

Answer (score 1):

Everything you do in your Human() constructor doesn't affect the internal properties of the Human object created at all.

Here is a variant of the Human() constructor that solves your problem:

```
public Human() {
    ArrayList<String> randomnames = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int j=1;j<10;j++) {
        randomnames.add("Namn"+j);
    }

    age = (int) (Math.random()*100);

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomnames.size());

    name = randomnames.get(index); 
}
```

Comment: This can be shortened even farther since we don't really need to create all `Namn{0-9}` just to pick one of them. We can simply use `name = "Namn"+rarandomGenerator.nextInt(10);` instead of whole loop. We can also replace `(int) (Math.random()*100);` with `rarandomGenerator.nextInt(100)` to make it more readable.

Comment: Why is the arraylist needed? You can use `randomGenerator.nextInt(10);`

Comment: THANK YOU! I just removed my last row in the Human()-constructor, and replaced rage=age, rname=name, and it solved it!

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in another answer, this does not work:

```
Human randomPerson = new Human(rage,rname);
```

but using

```
this(rage, rname);
```

won't work either because it is not the first line in the constructor.

Link:  [Why do this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor)

So instead of calling the other constructor just do this :

```
this.age = rage;
this.name = rname;
```

Answer (score -2):

`ArrayList<String> randomnames = new ArrayList<String>();` is only *scoped* to `Human()`, and not `main()`. You don't need it to only pull a random name from the list.

Your `Human` class doesn't care about having an `ArrayList`. It has two fields, and that's it.

> In my main method, I want to create an arraylist of 9 random Humans

You need to make the random Humans in `main()`, not called from `new Human()`

Move that code entirely into `main()`, not duplicate its attempts there.

For example,

```
public static void main() {

    // Make your list
    List<Human> randomHumans = new ArrayList<>();
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        // Get the random data
        String randomName = "Namn"+j;
        int rage = (int) (Math.random()*100);

        // add the human
        randomHumans.add(new Human(randomName, rage););
    }

    System.out.println(randomHumans);
}
```

> one that uses the first constructor to create a human with a random age and name

That can simply be written as

```
public Human() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    this.name = "Namn"+randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    this.age = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
```