# Do I have to call super every time I extend a class and need its constructor to trigger?

Tags: java

Is there any way I can trigger class constructor automatically while extending from the class?

I have a class TestSet.java

```
public class TestSet {
    public TestSet(String name) {
        Logger.msg("Test set: " + name);
    }
}
```

And I would like for the constructor to trigger every time that I extend from this class.

It seems that I need to call the constructor "manually" with:

```
public class TC1SendAnEmail extends TestSet{

    //I have to type this every single time again and again...
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    public TC1SendAnEmail(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------

    public void run() {
        new EmailLogin().run();
        ...
    }

}
```

Which I would like to avoid. (Because I will be creating possibly hundreds/thousands of those extended classes.)

From what I have managed to research, I guess that this function is not implemented in Java. But it just seems weird that I would have to "copy-paste" the constructor again, again and again...

Maybe there is another solution that I dont see? (Maybe without even using the constructor to "do something every time an instance of a class that extends my TestSet class is created".)

EDIT:
Yes, I can see why you think that creating hundreds/thousands of subclasses is wrong. I am creating a big automation project. Every class of this type will be a "test". And there will be thousands of tests...

EDIT#2:
The point of this question was that I needed to trigger the superclass constructor every time I extend from it. My mistake was adding parameter to the superclass constructor. **If you don´t add a parameter to the constructor, then it is triggered automatically while extending.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor)

Comment: *(Because I will be creating possibly hundreds/thousands of those extended classes.)* then you're doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: why don't you try to create an abstract class and extend it

Comment: What is your goal? Maybe you're trying something out, that can be made much easier. (Because creating hundreds of different subclasses sounds really suspicios

Comment: If you need hundreds or thousands extensions of a specific class, then the implementation is likely faulty, based on the OOP paradigm.

Comment: @Lino My goal is to create classes that run different automated tests (or parts of these tests). I want to write the name of the "Test set" automatically - when its instance is created - instead of having to call a method for that every single time.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the wheel? This is what frameworks like JUnit are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments I kinda understand what you're trying to achieve. (Automatically printing the name of the current running test)

So what about the following snippet:

```
public class TestSet {
     public TestSet(){
         Logger.msg("Test set: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
     }
}
```

This baseclass just prints the name of the implementing class when it is created. E.g. when using the following class:

```
public class TC1SendAnEmail extends TestSet {
     // your methods
}
```

it prints:

> Test set: TC1SendAnEmail

This works, because in java the default constructor (constructor with no arguments) of the superclass doesn't have to be overridden, because the compiler will generate it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Otherwise, how will it know that you want to pass `name` into it and not some other parameter?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is replace this copy-paste code with some sort of [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
public class SO50215241 {

    public abstract static class TestSet {
        public TestSet() {
            System.out.println("Test set: " + getName());
        }

        abstract String getName();
    }

    public static class TC1SendAnEmail extends TestSet{

        @Override
        String getName() {
            return "TC1Name";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TC1SendAnEmail();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Test set: TC1Name
```

Then you can try to extend some specific version of `TestSet` for concrete implementations instead of extending `TestSet` itself.
Or calculate name dynamically inside `getName` method body.

Comment: Ha! This seems exactly like what I need. I will take a look at the "abstracts" (never worked with it) and try it out.