# Kotlin primary constructor calling secondary constructor

Tags: kotlin, class-constructors, multiple-constructors

Why does this not compile?

```
class test
{
  constructor() {
      var a = Date().day
      this(a)
  }

  constructor(a:Int) {
  }
}
```

error is:
Expression 'this' of type 'test' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found.

The suggested fix is to add this:

```
private operator fun invoke(i: Int) {}
```

Why?

Answer (score 8):

First, both of these constructors are secondary constructors. A primary constructor is one which is located outside of the body of the class.

Second, as described in the [documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors), the correct syntax to call another constructor is as follows:

```
class Test {
    constructor() : this(1) { }

    constructor(a: Int) { }
}
```

Comment: What if you need to do some calculations before calling the secondary constructor such as:

class test
{
    constructor()
    {
        var a = Date().day
        
        this(a)
    }


    constructor(a:Int)
    {

    }
}

Comment: You can't do this. This is a JVM restriction. If this was possible, the object would exist in an uninitialized state during the execution of `var a = Date()`, and this is not allowed.

Comment: wait... depending on what you calculate, you can, e.g. you may write: `constructor() : this(Date().day)` or maybe I just didn't understand your question correctly ;-) If it's a more complex calculation but you start from a new instance somewhere, you may use something like `constructor() : this(ComplexObject().let { /* complex function leading to Int */ })`

Answer (score 1):

```
class test constructor(){ // primary constructor (The primary constructor is part of the class header: it goes after the class name (and optional type parameters))

    constructor(a: Int) : this() { // secondary constructor

    }
}
```

If you class have define `primary constructor`, `secondary constructor` needs to delegate to the `primary constructor`.  See [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

I think `primary constructor` **can not** be called from `secondary constructor`.

You can think like this: secondary calls primary and primary calls secondary => endless loop => not possible

In your case, there are 2 `secondary constructor`, so you can do like

```
class test {

    constructor() : this(Date().day) // I see it quite like Java here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor

    constructor(a: Int) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Couple of things are wrong here:

- Classes should always use camel-case for their names (`test` -> `Test`)
- You cannot call another constructor as you tried to (calling `this(1)` inside of the other constructors body)

I think what you actually want is `a` being a property and alternatively initialize it with a default value. You could do it like this

```
class Test(val a: Int) {
    constructor() : this(1) // notice how you can omit an empty body
}
```

or even better, like this:

```
class Test(val a: Int = 1) // again an empty body can be omitted.
```

**Edit:**

If you need to do some calculations, as asked in the comment below Yole's answer:

```
class Test(val day: Int) {
    // you can use any expression for initialization
    constructor(millis: Long) : this(Date(millis).day) 
}
```

or if things get more complicated:

```
class Test(var day: Int) {
    // pass something (i.e. 1) to the primary constructor and set it properly in the body
    constructor(millis: Long) : this(1) { 
        // some code
        day = // initialize day
    }
}
```