# Java: super () not at the first line possible?

Tags: java, oop

Is it possible to call the constructor of a parent-class not at the first line of the child?

I would like to build something like this (see constructor B).

```
class A
{
   public A () {}
   public A (int x) { // do something }
}

class B extends A
{
  public B (int y)
  {
    if (y > 0) { super (y); }
  }
}
```

I think with the existence of a default-constructor it is called automatically. Without it it would need to call super for the 1st line in B ().

Is it possible to call the other constructor (with the parameter) AFTER the 1st line - or have the same effect?

Comment: [This question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor)

Comment: Adding that condition might be confusing anyways but if you have to do it, why not use a marker/default value, e.g. like `super(y > 0 ? y : default)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy for such questions exist JAVADOC:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

And there is pretty well explained.

The logic you would like to achieve you can do in a different way

```
class A
{
   public A () {}
   public A (int x) { 
        doSomething(x); 
   }
   protected doSomething(int x){// do something}
}

class B extends A
{
  public B (int y)
  {
    if(y > 0){
     doSomething(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is `Java language` thing, not a JVM one - JVM does not care what first to execute, `javac` does

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. `super()` must always be the first statement of the child's constructor. See for more details on why: [Why do this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

> Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the
>   subclass constructor.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html