# Is it safe to use "this instanceof …" or "getClass()" in a constructor?

Tags: java, instanceof

Does the Java language guarantee that the `instanceof` operator or the `getClass()` method applied to `this` in a constructor always applies to the deeper class in the hierarchy?

For example, if I want to limit the subclasses which are allowed to call a constructor from the superclass, I could do this:

```
class A {
  A() {
    final Class<?> clazz = getClass();
    if (clazz != A.class && clazz != B.class && clazz != C.class) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
  }
}
```

but I wonder whether the language guarantees that it will work or not.

Comment: While this will work, this isn’t an ideal way to do it.  Usually, this is accomplished by having all three classes in the same package, and making the constructor of class A package-protected (as your example code is already doing, by making the constructor neither public nor private nor protected).

Comment: @VGR I agree that the example is quite ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed.

There is a always an implicit call to `super()` as the first action of the constructor if you do not explicitly specify one. ([JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7))

The reason this constraint is enforced - rather than allowing the parent constructor to be called at any point - is so that all super classes are guaranteed to be initialized, whether that be `Object`, or any other super type. Every instance method of `Object` is safe to use at this point; `getClass` is no exception.

See also [Why do this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is essentially, ***on which object `getClass`is called?*** 
[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/jls13.pdf) Covers it as follows

> The keyword ***this*** may be used only in the following contexts:
>
> - the body of a constructor of a class (§8.8.7)
> - ...
>
> When  used  as  a  primary  expression,  the  keyword  ***this***  denotes 
>   a  value  that  is a  reference  to  the  object  for  which  the 
>   instance  method  or  default  method  was invoked (§15.12), ***or to the
>   object being constructed***.