# this constructor citation not working in java

Tags: java, object, this

I tried to apply the this() method for calling the same constructor in java for trying to make a constructor wehere just vy providing the name and the class it would select the parameters of the character but its not working, im new to using this in java.

```
type public class Jugador{
    //campos
    private String nombre;
    private String clase;
    private int vida;
    private int ad;
    private int ap;
    private int def;
    private int mr;

    //constructores
    private Jugador(String nombre, String clase, int vida, int ad, int ap, int def, int mr){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        if (clase.equals("hunter") || clase.equals("warrior") || clase.equals("assasin") || clase.equals("tank")){
            this.clase = clase;
        }
        else{
            this.clase = "normal";
        }
        this.vida = vida;
        this.ad = ad;
        this.ap = ap;
        this.def = def;
        this.mr = mr;
    }

    public Jugador(String nombre, String clase){
        if (clase.equals("hunter")){
            this(nombre, clase, 120, 50, 0, 40, 0);
        }
        else if (clase.equals("warrior")){
            this(nombre, clase, 100, 70, 0, 80, 0);
        }
        else if (clase.equals("assasin")){
            this(nombre, clase, 60, 120, 0, 20, 0);
        }
        else if (clase.equals("tank")){
            this(nombre, clase, 200, 20, 0, 80, 0);
        }
        else if(clase.equals("normal")){
            this(nombre, clase, 80, 80, 0, 80, 0);
        }
    }


    }here
```

Comment: Please post the error message. That is going to be necessary in order for us to make sure that we are looking at the same error.

Comment: When using `this()`, it must be the first statement, so you can't use an `if` statement and then `this()`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `this()` (or `super()`) inside an *if* statement. Calls to `this()` (or `super()`) has to to be the first statement in a constructor.

See [Why do this() and super() have to be the first statement in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-do-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor) post for why that is the case. <sup>1</sup>

There are several ways you can fix this. You can decide not to have a public constructor for the class and instead enable creating instance of the class via a *public static* method.

```
public static class Jugador {
    //campos
    private String nombre;
    private String clase;
    private int vida;
    private int ad;
    private int ap;
    private int def;
    private int mr;

    private Jugador(String nombre, String clase, int vida, int ad, int ap, int def, int mr) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        if (clase.equals("hunter") || clase.equals("warrior") || clase.equals("assasin") || clase.equals("tank")) {
            this.clase = clase;
        } else {
            this.clase = "normal";
        }
        this.vida = vida;
        this.ad = ad;
        this.ap = ap;
        this.def = def;
        this.mr = mr;
    }

    public static Jugador buildJugador(String nombre, String clase) {
        if (clase.equals("hunter")) {
            return new Jugador(nombre, clase, 120, 50, 0, 40, 0);
        } else if (clase.equals("warrior")) {
            return new Jugador(nombre, clase, 100, 70, 0, 80, 0);
        } else if (clase.equals("assasin")) {
            return new Jugador(nombre, clase, 60, 120, 0, 20, 0);
        } else if (clase.equals("tank")) {
            return new Jugador(nombre, clase, 200, 20, 0, 80, 0);
        } else if (clase.equals("normal")) {
            return new Jugador(nombre, clase, 80, 80, 0, 80, 0);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid value passed for clase");
        }
    }
}
```

Then the callers cannot directly invoke the constructor (as it is private), but use the `buildJugador` method as,

```
Jugador jugador = Jugador.buildJugador("some-value", "hunter");
```

---

<sup>1</sup> That might change in the future with [JEP 447: Statements before super()](https://openjdk.org/jeps/447). But it is not planned to be part of any future Java release as of now.

Comment: JEP 447 is interesting, but according to the issue tracker, there is no target release for the preview yet.  IMO, the preview is highly unlikely to land *before* Java 22.

Comment: @StephenC Yes. It may not even make it at all (be dropped for some reason). That is why I've said *it might* change in the future depending on how the JEP goes

Comment: Agreed.  Just filling in the dotted lines for readers who are overly eager and/or who don't understand how innovations happen in Java.

Comment: @StephenC I've rephrased it to be more clear

Comment: @user16320675 The JEP title has the word *preview*. We could say the JEP is in review. Anyway I've removed the word *preview* to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... a constructor wehere just vy providing the name and the class it would select the parameters of the character ..."*

So, instead of utilizing a *private* constructor,

```java
private Jugador(String nombre, String clase, int vida, int ad, int ap, int def, int mr)
```

Use a *private* method to add the values, *vida*, *ad*, etc.

```java
private void values(int vida, int ad, int ap, int def, int mr) {
    this.vida = vida;
    this.ad = ad;
    this.ap = ap;
    this.def = def;
    this.mr = mr;
}
```

Then, from your *public* constructor, just apply *values* accordingly.

I merged your code from the *private* constructor here.

```java
public Jugador(String nombre, String clase){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.clase = switch (clase) {
        case "hunter", "warrior", "assasin", "tank" -> clase;
        default -> "normal";
    };
    switch (clase) {
        case "hunter" -> values(120, 50, 0, 40, 0);
        case "warrior" -> values(100, 70, 0, 80, 0);
        case "assasin" -> values(60, 120, 0, 20, 0);
        case "tank" -> values(200, 20, 0, 80, 0);
        case "normal" -> values(80, 80, 0, 80, 0);
    }
}
```