# Why is the difference between an expression and a statement

Tags: c, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement)

What does expression mean? Something that evaluates to something, returns a value?

How is it different from a statement. Can a statement contain an expression and vice versa?

Comment: Pretty much a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement

Answer (score 14):

Expressions do "return" a value, though they may be cast to `(void)`. Statements don't evaluate to anything and only have side effects.

E.g. `;` is a statement by itself, evaluates to nothing, and has no side effects.

Answer (score 9):

An expression is a instruction to be executed that returns a value (even if it returns a `void`).

A statement is used to form the sequence of a program (e.g. `if-then`, `while-do` statements). A statement can be simple or complex and can contain 0 or more expression.

As @Frédéric Hamidi said, a `;` is a valid statement.

Wiki on:

- [Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_%28programming%29)
- [Statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28programming%29)