# Allocate array without specifying size

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, new-operator

Does the following construction valid according to the C++ standards and what can I do with the arr after this statement?

```
char* arr = new char[];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's invalid in all standards. What would be the semantic?

Comment: I think the exception that *could* make that valid would be user-defined placement new, where user-defined args are empty; but in that case, you'd need to pass the address, so, nope.

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @didierc idk, I just saw this code in the C++ project

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not allowed. The grammar for *new-expression*s in [expr.new]/1 specifies

> *noptr-new-declarator*:
>         `[` *expression* `]` *attribute-specifier-seq* <sub>opt</sub>
>            *noptr-new-declarator* [ *constant-expression* ] *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub>

Clearly there is no *expression* between the brackets in your code. And it woudn't make sense either: How could you allocate an array of unknown length?

If you need an array whose size is to be changed dynamically, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: How is `expression` defined?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It's anything that's not a `statement`. As that isn't very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846727/why-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement

Answer (score 1):

C++ compiler offen defines extension allowing to declare array of size = 0. Usualy it can be useful for declaring last field in a structure so you can choose length of such array during structure allocation.

```
struct A
{
    float something;
    char arr[];
};
```

So if you like to allocate such A with let say arr to have 7 elements, you do:

```
A* p = (A*)malloc( sizeof(A) + sizeof(char)*7) ;
```

You should note that sizeof(A) is equal to sizeof(float), so for compiler your arr field is 0 sized.

Now you can use your arr field up to 7 indexes:

```
p->arr[3]='d';
```

Comment: Although this feature indeed exists in some implementations, this is not a dynamic allocation of an array using `new`.