# error when trying to use pass keyword in one line if statement

Tags: python

stumped that this works:

```
if 5 % 2 == 0:
        print "no remainder"
else:
        pass
```

but not this:

```
print "no remainder" if 5% 2 == 0 else pass

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Just a heads up: `pass` keyword here is unnecessary. You could simply write `5 % 2  == 0: print "No remainder"`, and skip the `else: pass` entirely.

Comment: print "no remainder" if 5% 2 == 0 else 0

Comment: +1 to what msvalkon said; `else pass` is the same as no `else` clause. Also, the incorrect syntax arises from the use of `print`, not from the `else`

Comment: but what i'm trying to do is print out the time it took to process every 1000 rows, if it's still iterating up to the next 1000, i don't want anything to happen

Comment: @DerekKrantz You just need a plain `if` statement then, like the one in my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The latter is not an `if` statement, rather an expression (I mean, `print` is a statement, but the rest is being interpreted as an expression, which fails). Expressions have values. `pass` doesn't, because it's a statement.

You may be seeing it as two statements (`print or pass`), but the interpreter sees it differently:

```
expr = "no remainder" if 5% 2 == 0 else pass
print expr
```

and the first line is problematic because it mixes an expression and a statement.

A one-line `if` statement is a different thing:

```
if 5 % 2 == 0: print "no remainder"
```

this can be called a one-line `if` statement.

P.S. Ternary expressions are referred to as "conditional expressions" in the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

A ternary expression uses the syntax you tried to use, but it needs two *expressions* and a condition (also an expression):

```
expr1 if cond else expr2
```

and it takes the value of `expr1` if `bool(cond) == True` and `expr2` otherwise.

Comment: thanks lev. of course, typing "what is an expression in python" nets this as the top result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782590/what-is-an-expression-in-python

Comment: @DerekKrantz After reading the linked post, it appears that expressions are actually statements, too. But anyway, it's enough to understand that and expression is something that has a value.