# Is a function call an expression in python?

Tags: python, function, syntax, expression, call

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782649/2403580), a function call is a statement, but in the course I'm following in Coursera they say a function call is an expression.

*So this is my guess: a function call does something, that's why it's a statement, but after it's called it evaluates and passes a value, which makes it also an expression.*

Is a function call an expression?

Comment: The term "**does something**" is very vague and misleading, don't read too much into the words.

Comment: I think that answer is a bit confusing, or maybe even misleading. But if you read the comments to the answer, they explain everything. (The other answers help as well). A function call is an expression. Since any expressions is also an expression statement, that means a function call is also a statement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A call is [an expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls); it is listed in the Expressions reference documentation.

If it was a statement, you could not use it as part of an expression; statements *can* contain expressions, but not the other way around.

As an example, `return expression` is a statement; it *uses* expressions to determine it's behaviour; the result of the expression is what the current function returns. You can use a call as part of that expression:

```
return some_function()
```

You cannot, however, use `return` as part of a call:

```
some_function(return)
```

That would be a syntax error.

It is the `return` that 'does something'; it ends the function and returns the result of the expression. It's not the expression itself that makes the function return.

If a python call was *not* an expression, you'd never be able to mix calls and other [expression atoms](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atoms) into more complex expressions.

Comment: Wow! Thanks everyone!
I leaned a LOT thanks to you guys! What a great first experience here in S.O.! :)

Answer (score 0):

Function calls are expressions, so you can use them in statements such as `print` or `=`:

```
x = len('hello')        # The expression evaluates to 5
print hex(48)           # The expression evaluates to '0x30'
```

In Python, functions are objects just like integers and strings.  Like other objects, functions have attributes and methods.   What makes functions callable is the `__call__` method:

```
>>> def square(x):
        return x * x

>>> square(10)
100
>>> square.__call__(10)
100
```

The parentheses dispatch to the `__call__` method.

This is at the core of how Python works.  Hope you've found these insights helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! It is really useful! I tried to select both answers, but I can't. Learned a lot! All the best!

Answer (score 0):

expression are also statements in python. A function is an expression because it returns a value but expressions in python are also statements. [expression statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements)