# What's the evaluation order of conditional expression in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I know the conditional expression in Python is X if C else Y, but I got some problems in using it.

I have two codes to be compared.

**Code 1:**

```
def fun(p):
    if len(p) >= 2:
        p[1] = 'Ok'
    else:
        p.append('Ok')
p = [1]
fun(p)
print p
```

**Output of code 1:**

```
[1, 'Ok']
```

**Code 2:**

```
def fun(p):
    (p[1] = 'Ok') if (len(p) >= 2) else p.append('OK')

p = [1]
fun(p)
print p
```

**Output of code 2:**

```
    (p[1] = 'Ok') if (len(p) >= 2) else p.append('OK')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know in code 1, whose format is "if C : X else: Y", the evaluation order is:

1. C
2. X
3. Y

Code 2 throws a syntax error, the reason may be p[1] doesn't exist. So I guess the format "X if C else Y" is evaluated as follows:

1. X
2. C
3. Y

But that is only my guess. does anyone know the real reason why code 2 is wrong while code 1 is right?

Comment: Note that assignments are statements and can't appear in expression contexts. That is the reason for the error in Code 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you have a `SyntaxError` is because Python differentiates between **statements** and **expressions**.

Assignments, like

```
p[1] = 'Ok'
```

are **statements** and can't be part of an **expression**, including the conditional expression. See [What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/python-what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement) for more info.

Order of evaluation doesn't come into it -- `SyntaxError`s happen before **any** code is evaluated, when its being parsed.

In both `if` statements and conditional expressions, The order of evaluations is **ether**

1. Condition
2. True Statement

**or**

1. Condition
2. False Statement

So, in

```
if condition:
    true_statement
else:
    false_statement
```

or

```
true_statement if condition else false_statement
```

only the true **or** the fase statement is evaluated, depending on the truthiness of the condition.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I do know the differences now.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is no expression (others pointed that out).  Hence the syntax error.

Regarding your question concerning **evaluation order**:

In **if-else** expressions(!) first the condition operand is evaluated, then either the then-operand (leftmost) or the else-operand (rightmost) is evaluated.  The other operand is *not* evaluated.

In **or**-expressions the operands are evaluated from leftmost to rightmost (`a or b or c or d or ...`) but only until one is found whose Boolean value is True.  The remaining expressions are *not* evaluated.

In **and**-expressions the operands are evaluated from leftmost to rightmost (`a and b and c and d and ...`) but only until one is found whose Boolean value is False.  The remaining expressions are *not* evaluated.

Inner expressions are evaluated before outer expressions (of course): `third(second(first()))`

In **all other cases** (`a() + b()`, `f(g(), h())`, `a[b[c]] = d() + e`) the order is defined as [specified](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/evalorder.html).  Typically it's left-to-right except for assignment (where it is right before left).

Answer (score 0):

As Dan D. points out, you can't have statements in expression contexts.

In the interest of learning -- I do not recommend doing it this way -- I'll show you how you could use the inline `X if C else Y` to accomplish what you're attempting to do:

```
def fun(p):
    p.__setitem__(1, 'Ok') if len(p) >= 2 else p.append('OK')
```

As you can see, your fist version is much more readable.

Comment: Is readability the only reason why you wouldn't do this? (It seems impolite to use the ternary operator syntax for a side effect.)

Comment: @Li-aung Of course you're right -- this is misusing the ternary operator since we're just throwing away the answer (which is either `None` or `None`). But at least we're explicit about it -- there's no doubt that this is done expressly for the side effects.

Comment: @lazyr Thanks for giving me another solution.