# Return statement using ternary operator

Tags: python, ternary-operator

In `c` I can do something like:

```
int minn(int n, int m){
 return (n<m)? n:m
}
```

But in python I am not able to achieve the same:

```
def minn(n,m):
    return n if n<m else return m
```

this gives `Syntax Error`

I know I can do something like :

```
def minn(n,m):
    return min(n,m)
```

My question is that, can't I use ternary operator in python.

Comment: there is nothing called two return statements! `return (n<m)? n:m` returns only one value, either n or m, based on the comparison `n<m`

Comment: @Curious I had a weird confusion,now its clear.

Comment: in python you could write the same thing as `return n if n<m else m`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Your C code doesn't contain two `return` statements. Neither should your python code... The translation of your ternary expression is `n if n<m else m`, so just use that expression when you return the value:

```
def minn(n,m):
    return n if n<m else m
```

Comment: Hmm. Kinda obvious if you think about it, but considering I have a computer science degree and 4 years of Java/Software Engineering experience, I was still scratching my head on this one. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 14):

```
def minn(n,m):
    return n if n<m else m
```

The `expr1 if expr2 else expr3` expression is an expression, not a statement. `return` is a statement (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/python-what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement) question)

Because expressions cannot contain statements, your code fails.