# Augmented assignment in the middle of expression causes SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax-error, augmented-assignment

In my code I have these lines:

```
if numVotes == 0:
    avId in self.disconnectedAvIds or self.resultsStr += curStr
```

When I run the code I get this error?

```
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you are mixing a boolean expression with an assignment statement

Comment: You cant do += im your loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment

```
self.resultsStr += curStr
```

is a statement. [Statements can not be part of expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728147/190597). Therefore, use an `if-statement`:

```
if avId not in self.disconnectedAvIds:
    self.resultsStr += curStr
```

Python bans assignments inside of expressions because it is thought they frequently lead to bugs. For example,

```
if x = 0    # banned
```

is too close too

```
if x == 0   # allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

`avId in self.disconnectedAvIds` will return a boolean value. `or` is used to evaluate between two boolean values, so it's correct so far.

`self.resultsStr += curStr` is an assignment to a variable. An assignment to a variable is of the form `lvalue = rvalue` where `lvalue` is a variable you can assign values to and `rvalue` is some expression that evaluates to the data type of the `lvalue`. This will not return a boolean value, so the expression is illegal.

If you want to change the value `if avId is in self.disconnectedAvIds` then use an if statement.

```
if avId in self.disconnectedAvIds:
    self.resultsStr += curStr
```