# Python: using Perl style logical not and boolean negation

Tags: python, perl, operators

What is the python way to do this equivalent of this Perl line?

`! (90 % 15) && print "yes"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
not (90 % 15) and print("yes")
```

---

If you use python 2 (and >= 2.6), you need to explicitly import `print_function`

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

This is needed because the right operand of the boolean `and` need to be an [expression (and can not be a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728147/428236)). In python2, `print` is a statement, thus you need to import the `print` function from python3, available in the `__future__` module. Note that you could also use `sys.stdout.write("yes\n")` to achieve the same goal.

Comment: This would require `from __future__ import print_function`, wouldn't it?

Comment: So this is using print(), a function from the future library, versus a print builtin?

Comment: Regular `print` in Python is a statement, and cannot be used as part of an expression.

Comment: That exact line of code is also valid Perl, and reads better than the one with `!` and `&&` :)