# Questions about Python conceptual hierarchy

Tags: python, syntax, structure

I'm reading through [Learning Python (3<sup>rd</sup> Edition)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596513986.do), by Mark Lutz, and I'm in the portion that is dealing with the nuts and bolts of Python syntax.

He defines the Python language-structure hierarchy as follows:

1. Programs are composed of modules
2. Modules contain statements
3. Statements contain expressions
4. Expressions create and process objects

I'm a little confused about the definition of Python statements.
I've heard Expressions described as anything that is a value, but also can contain things like addition, etc.

Is it safe to say that statements are structured operations on expressions that drive a module's logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are almost there.

Expressions are something that evaluate to some **value**.

On the other hand, statements are something that cause some **action**.

That action can be on some object, based on result of an expression which may or may not involve some other object(s).

Comment: This is a great and concise answer!

Comment: I also like the compactness of this, but since _all_ values in Python, and hence all expression results, are objects, I'd recommend rewording the last sentence - maybe "That action can be on some object (possible the result of an expression), or the state of the program structure (creation of a new class), or the control flow (jumping back and forth with e.g. `if` or `for`)".

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset I've edited a bit. Hope it's better now.

Comment: It's worth being explicit, too, that any expression by itself may constitute a statement, although only expressions that have side effects are useful as a statement.

Answer (score 2):

I found this with a quick Google search, is it what you where looking for?

[What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python)

"Statements (see 1, 2), on the other hand, are everything that can make up a line (or several lines) of Python code. Note that expressions are statements as well."

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite wary of classifications like this, and especially attempts to make them into a hierarchy. An expression can also be, for example, a function call; I guess that falls into your "anything that is a value" definition since a function always returns a value even if it is None.

A statement is really everything else; assignment, flow control (eg defining a for or while loop, try/except, break, continue...), the introduction of a function or a class definition (the `def` or `class` keywords), and so on.