# Python Class dynamic attribute access

Tags: python, dynamic, attributes, eval

I want to access a class attribute by a string with its name.

Something like:

```
class a:
    b=[]

c='b'
eval('a.'+c+'=1')
```

But that doesn't work in Python.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
In [1]: class a:
   ...:     b = []
   ...:     

In [2]: setattr(a, 'b', 1)

In [3]: a.b
Out[3]: 1
```

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) for the reverse:

```
In [4]: getattr(a, 'b')
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: getattr(a, 'x', 'default')
Out[5]: 'default'
```

I very much suspect, though, that there is a better way to achieve whatever your goal is. Have you tried using a dictionary instead of a class?

Comment: Definitaly more cleaver. I want to save and retreive Gui Widget values.

Comment: @GeneralExeption: i put in the other direction for you

Answer (score 2):

`eval` is for evaluation, use `exec` to 'execute' statements:

```
exec('a.'+c+'=1')
```

Yet, consider the risk of using [both](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/). And you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) for the difference between expressions and statements.

Since you are looking to set attribute by name, `setattr` explained in [hop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34831594/1327005) is a better practice, and safer than using `exec`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a quit answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you think you need `eval` or `exec`, you are wrong.

Comment: Note that using eval/exec is dangerous as this probably can open a code execution vulnerability

Comment: I want to save the widget values of a GUI in a file. But when I retreive the file I get attribute name and values to set.

Comment: @GeneralExeption the best way to update an attribute by name is not using eval or exect because they are too risky. Use `setattr` : check the other answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/34831594/1327005