# Invalid syntax when using single equals to compare in an if statement

Tags: python

I get a `SyntaxError` from this code:

```
if wallDirection = '-X':
    xAxis = -buildingSectionWidth
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see [What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) An `if` statement requires an *expression* as its condition.

`wallDirection = '-X'` is a statement that assigns `wallDirection` to the value `-X`. The expression you likely want here is `wallDirection == '-X'`. The operator that tests for equality is `==`, not `=`.

```
if wallDirection == '-X':
    xAxis = -buildingSectionWidth
```