# list __iadd__, += and return value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have noticed some strange behaviour with list extension return values.

I have read this thread [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)

but it still does not make sense.

This is what I did:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> print(l.extend([1]))
None
>>> print(l.__iadd__([1]))
[1, 2, 1, 1]
>>> print(l += [1])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
print(l += [1])
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I understand that `extend` does not return the extended object, but `None`. Not helpful, but I get it.

Now `__iadd__` behaves differently, which is weird, since I read that this basically calls extend for a list.

But the third one baffles me. I thought `+=` was shorthand for `__iadd__`, so why do I get a `SyntaxError` here? Especially since `__iadd__` returns the modified list, which would make sense to pass on as a return value. But it seems I can't use `+=` (or `*=` for that matter, e.g. with integers) in function calls.

Is that by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l.__iadd__(val)` is a function call, that is, *an expression*.

`l += [1]` is an assignment, that is, *a statement*.

Argument values (the ones you have supplied to `print` in this case) are not allowed to be statements, *only expressions*, simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even aware of the distinction. Very interesting. If anyone else also didn't know, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) a good explanation.

Comment: @Niko If you're interested in more technical details, Python has 3 full chapters for expressions and simple and compound statements in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) Might want to bookmark it for some later point :-)

Answer (score 0):

`__iadd__` is used to implement `+=`, but the two are not identical. `l += [1]` is still a *statement*, while `l.__iadd__([1])` is an *expression*.