# Python swap adjacent elements in a list (Syntax Error)

Tags: python, list, syntax-error, swap

This is my list:

```
 l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to swap adjacent elements, so the list should result in this:

```
l = [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

I know that there are lots of solutions for this and I think I found one:

```
def swap(l):
    return l[::2], l[1::2] = l[1::2], l[::2]
```

Anyhow I am still getting this Error:

```
file.py on line 2
    return l[::2], l[1::2] = l[1::2], l[::2]
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any hints or ideas how to solve this are highly appreciated. (Working on Python2)

Comment: You can not `return` an assignment statement just an expression. Given you are changing the `l` value itself you probably don't need the `return` statement at all.

Comment: Assignment is a statement, not an expression. It cannot be returned, because it doesn't evaluate to a value.

Comment: Wow you guys are fast - thanks, given I want to return the list, is there a way to do that without an additional line?

Comment: Note: you are currently only swapping the first 2 elements, swap all elements in the list then you can use slice assignment (note: the list needs to be even length): `l[::2], l[1::2] = l[1::2], l[::2] -> [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4]`

Comment: You are modifying in place you probably want to create a new list and return it, e.g. `return [x for pair in zip(*[iter(l)]*2) for x in reversed(pair)]`

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, sorry for the duplicate (I obviously asked the wrong questions while doing my research).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `return`:

```
def swap(l):
    l[0], l[1] = l[1], l[0]
```

You can only return *expressions*, not full *statements*.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728147/7007605) for an explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be

```
def swap(l):
    l[0], l[1] = l[1], l[0]
```

Comment: No need to return `l` since the assignment will be done inplace anyway.

Comment: yes correct. @DeepSpace