# Syntax error when using list comprehensions in Python 3.6 to loop over and compare dependency triplets for two sentences

Tags: python, performance, numpy, nlp, list-comprehension

I have the following two sentences:

1. I want to go home.
2. I would like to leave.

My goal is to quantify similarity between the two sentences using a kernel suggested in 
[this paper](https://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/~ozgur/papers/617_Paper.pdf). I extract all the dependency triplets for each sentence. These are 3 item tuples containing all the relations between words in the sentence and look like *(tail, relationship, head)*.

To calculate similarity, I need to loop through every possible combination of triplet across sentences and add a particular number to the similarity score based on how many nodes match and whether the relationship matches.

I attempted using list comprehensions inside a for loop since I figured it would be more efficient than another nested for loop but am getting a syntax error. Here's my code:

```
sim = 0
theta = 2.5

for d1 in deps1:
    [sim += theta for d2 in deps2 if ((d1[0]==d2[0] or d1[2]==d2[2]) and d1[1]==d2[1])]
    [sim += 1 for d2 in deps2 if ((d1[0]==d2[0] or d1[2]==d2[2]) and d1[1]!=d2[1])]
```

For reference, here's what deps1 and deps2 look like when printed:

```
[('I', 'nsubj', 'want'), ('want', 'ROOT', 'want'), ('to', 'aux', 'go'), ('go', 'xcomp', 'want'), ('home', 'advmod', 'go')]
[('I', 'nsubj', 'like'), ('would', 'aux', 'like'), ('like', 'ROOT', 'like'), ('to', 'aux', 'leave'), ('leave', 'xcomp', 'like')]
```

Questions:

1. What's the correct syntax to do this with a list comprehension?
2. Is there a more efficient way, maybe using numpy(?), to do this computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can use **expressions** in a list comprehension but not **statements**. You may want to look at the [diffence between expressions and statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) in Python.

As of your question in the comment on how to compute `((# of matching nodes) * (1 if the relationship doesn't match, 2.5 if it does))`, which is the numerator of the **SABK** similarity function of the paper in your question, you can do it using a generator and the `sum` function:

```
theta = 2.5
sim = sum((((d1[0] == d2[0]) + (d1[2] == d2[2])) * (theta if d1[1] == d2[1] else 1) for d1, d2 in product(deps1, deps2)))
```

Or, if you want to separate the code for the function of the similarity per sentence, which improves the readability of the code:

```
def sim_per_sentence(d1, d2):
    matching_nodes = (d1[0] == d2[0]) + (d2[0] == d2[0])
    relation_sim = theta if d1[1] == d2[1] else 1
    return matching_nodes * relation_sim

sim = sum((sim_per_sentence(d1, d2) for d1, d2 in product(deps1, deps2)))
```

Remark that it may be way more efficient to use a [generator expression instead of a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) if you have many elements in `deps1` and `deps2`, as the individual results of each iteration do not need to be stored in memory.

Comment: That's a good point about generators, especially since I don't really need to manipulate the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want to achieve is a cumulative result but you can't do it in that way because the expression `sim += theta` is not returning an independent object to be considered as an item of final list result. What you can do instead is multiplying the `theta` variable with a counter or create a list of `theta`s and then create a cumulative version using `np.cumsum()` or `itertools.accumulate()` which is not recommended unless you want to keep both original result and the cumulative one.

Also, instead of using two loops you can use `itertools.product` in order to create all the combinations of triplets and as counter you can use `itertools.count`.

```
In [36]: from itertools import product, count

In [37]: c = count(1)

In [38]: [2.5*next(c) for d1, d2 in product(deps1,deps2) if ((d1[0]==d2[0] or d1[2]==d2[2]) and d1[1]==d2[1])]
Out[38]: [2.5, 5.0]
```

And to do both conditions in one list comprehension you can do the following:

```
[(d1[1]!=d2[1] or 2.5)*next(c) for d1, d2 in product(deps1,deps2) if d1[0]==d2[0] or d1[2]==d2[2]]
```

Comment: Works for matching relationship between tuples! What's the best way to extend it to compute ((# of matching nodes) * (1 if the relationship doesn't match, 2.5 if it does))? The nodes are the first and third elements in the tuples, the relationship between them is the second.