# Difference between an Expression and Statement in Dart?

Tags: dart, expression, dart-pub

Since different languages have different definitions for an expression and a statement, what is the difference between them in Dart?

Comment: I don't think there is much difference between different languages. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728162/217408

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/doexxec.tex#L9854-L9871 vs https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/dartLangSpec.tex#L5040-L5042

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still new to Dart but with previous knowledge (and reading dart language tour):

- **Expressions** usually evaluate to something, for example when using conditional expression, `condition ? expr1 : expr2` has a value of `expr1` or `expr2`.
- **Statements** have no value or usually do nothing to change values directly.

A `statement` **contains** `expressions`, but an `expression` **can’t contain** a `statement`.

Above is my explanation of bullet point I tried to simplify for you, found when reading [language tour on category important concepts](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts) that goes like this:

> Dart has both *expressions* (which have runtime values) and *statements* (which don’t). For example, the *conditional expression* `condition ? expr1 : expr2` has a value of `expr1` or `expr2`. Compare that to an *if-else statement*, which has no value. A statement often contains one or more expressions, but an expression can’t directly contain a statement.

Answer (score 12):

## Short answer

Expressions are *values*, and statements *do things*.

## Examples

This makes more sense if you can see examples.

#### Expressions

An expression has a value at runtime.

- `42`
- `true`
- `hello`
- `1 + 1`
- `x`
- `myObject`
- `myInt + 1`
- `k++`
- `p > 0`
- `condition ? expr1 : expr2`
- `'hello'.toUpperCase()`
- `myObject.toString()`
- `myObject.someMethod()`
- `myObject?.someProperty?.someMethod()`
- `myString.isEmpty`
- `[1, 2, 3]`
- `[...list1]`
- `<String, String>{...a, ...b}`

#### Statements

A statement does something and in itself doesn't have a value at runtime. Statements are not expressions, but they can contain expressions.

- `myInt = 1;`
- `print('hello');`
- `return null;`
- `if (name != null) { return name; } else { return 'Guest'; }`
- `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { message.write('!'); }`
- `break;`
- `while (!isDone()) { doSomething(); }`
- `yield k++;`
- `assert(text != null);`
- `throw FormatException('Expected at least 1 section');`
- `void distanceTo(Point other) => throw UnimplementedError();`

> ***Note**: Most of the examples here came by searching the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides) for the keywords **expression** and **statement**.*

Comment: Is `int a = 10 + 20` an expression or a statement?

Comment: @iDecode, Since `int a = 10 + 20;` _does_ something (declares an integer variable and then assigns it a value), it is a statement. The right-hand side `10 + 20` is an expression (with a _value_ of `30`).

Comment: I found example contradictory to `myInt = 1;` being statement. It's `lambda() => myInt = 1;`. Why? Look at fat arrow explanation in the docs: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions. It says "Only an expression—not a statement—can appear between the arrow (=>) and the semicolon (;)". The aforementioned example compiles, linter doesn't complain, so it's an expression, not a statement.

Comment: @Przemo. Good question. I opened an issue about it [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/4582).

Comment: @PrzemekTom
In the "switch expressions" chapter, the documentation talks about "Expression statements". I guess that it talks about this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, an expression or mathematical expression is a finite combination of symbols that is well-formed according to rules that depend on the context. Mathematical symbols can designate numbers (constants), variables, operations, functions, brackets, punctuation, and grouping to help determine order of operations, and other aspects of logical syntax.

The same thing in Dart.

Statement in this case can be desribed as a combination of expressions and possible other symbols that required for correct notation of concrete statement.

In Dart, the statement can be empty which means that statement does not contains any expressions. Empty statement can be stated by well-formed notation or determined by context.

Example (in pseudo code) of `if-else` statement.

`if (expression) { statement(s) } else { statement(s) }`