# What is the exact difference between the expression and the statement in programming

Tags: expression, statements

I am confused with the terms expressions and statements.
Will it differ from language to language?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python

Comment: Your confusion confuses us as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these terms don't mean the same thing in SQL as they do in Java or C#.  So yes, I think it will differ somewhat.