# What does a yield inside a yield do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield

Consider the following code:

```
def mygen():
     yield (yield 1)
a = mygen()
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
```

The output yields:

```
1
None
```

What does the interpreter do at the "outside" yield exactly?

Comment: Here is a classic very nice talk that has since been superceded with async/await that can explain it (the existing answers are also good!): https://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`a` is a generator object. The first time you call `next` on it, the body is evaluated up to the first `yield` expression (that is, the first to be evaluated: the inner one). That `yield` produces the value `1` for `next` to return, then blocks until the next entry into the generator. That is produced by the second call to `next`, which does *not* send any value *into* the generator. As a result, the first (inner) `yield` evaluates to `None`. That value is used as the argument for the outer `yield`, which becomes the return value of the second call to `next`. If you were to call `next` a third time, you would get a `StopIteration` exception.

Compare the use of the `send` method  (instead of `next`) to change the return value of the first `yield` expression.

```
>>> a = mygen()
>>> next(a)
1
>>> a.send(3)  # instead of next(a)
3
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

A more explicit way of writing the generator would have been

```
def mygen():
    x = yield 1
    yield x

a = mygen()
print(a.send(None))  # outputs 1, from yield 1
print(a.send(5))     # makes yield 1 == 5, then gets 5 back from yield x
print(a.send(3))     # Raises StopIteration, as there's nothing after yield x
```

---

Prior to Python 2.5, the `yield` *statement* provided one-way communication between a caller and a generator; a call to `next` would execute the generator up to the next `yield` statement, and the value provided by the `yield` keyword would serve as the return value of `next`. The generator
would also suspend at the point of the `yield` statement, waiting for the next call to `next` to resume.

In Python 2.5, the `yield` statement was replaced* with the `yield` *expression*, and generators acquired a `send` method. `send` works very much like `next`, except it can take an argument. (For the rest of this, assume that `next(a)` is equivalent to `a.send(None)`.) A generator starts execution after a call to `send(None)`, at which point it executes up to the first `yield`, which returns a value as before. Now, however, the expression blocks until the *next* call to `send`, at which point the `yield` expression evaluates to the argument passed to `send`. A generator can now *receive* a value when it resumes.

---

* Not quite replaced; kojiro's answer goes into more detail about the subtle difference between a `yield` statement and `yield` expression.

Comment: You seem to be using "first" to mean "inner". Although the inner `yield` is *evaluated* first, it is *written* second, so I think that terminology is confusing. Also, I assume by "genenerator" you mean "generator".

Answer (score 28):

`yield` has two forms, [expressions and statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement). They're mostly the same, but I most often see them in the `statement` form, where the result would not be used.

```
def f():
    yield a thing
```

But in the expression form, `yield` has a value:

```
def f():
    y = yield a thing
```

In your question, you're using both forms:

```
def f():
    yield ( # statement
        yield 1 # expression
    )
```

When you iterate over the resulting generator, you get first the result of the inner yield expression

```
>>> x=f()
>>> next(x)
1
```

At this point, the inner expression has also produced a value that the outer statement can use

```
>>> next(x)
>>>  # None
```

and now you've exhausted the generator

```
>>> next(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

To understand more about statements vs expressions, there are good answers in other stackoverflow questions: [What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python)

Comment: Great answer - I'm wondering if anyone knows a realistic application for this syntax.

Comment: @JamieCounsell Allowing a generator to receive a value makes it very close to a coroutine; the only difference is that a generator cannot specify where control goes when leaving the body of the generator; you always go back to wherever control came *from*.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> def mygen():
...     yield (yield 1)
...
>>> a = mygen()
>>>
>>> a.send(None)
1
>>> a.send(5)
5
>>> a.send(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> def mygen():
...     yield 1
...
>>> def mygen2():
...     yield (yield 1)
...
>>> def mygen3():
...     yield (yield (yield 1))
...
>>> a = mygen()
>>> a2 = mygen2()
>>> a3 = mygen3()
>>>
>>> a.send(None)
1
>>> a.send(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> a2.send(None)
1
>>> a2.send(0)
0
>>> a2.send(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> a3.send(None)
1
>>> a3.send(0)
0
>>> a3.send(1)
1
>>> a3.send(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

Every other yield simply waits for a value to be passed into, generator don't only give data but they also receive it.

---

```
>>> def mygen():
...     print('Wait for first input')
...     x = yield # this is what we get from send
...     print(x, 'is received')
...
>>> a = mygen()
>>> a.send(None)
Wait for first input
>>> a.send('bla')
bla is received
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

`yield` gives the next value when you continue if you get it, and if it is not used for giving the next value, it is being used for receiving the next

```
>>> def mygen():
...     print('Wait for first input')
...     x = yield # this is what we get from send
...     yield x*2 # this is what we give
...
>>> a = mygen()
>>> a.send(None)
Wait for first input
>>> a.send(5)
10
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any generator exhausts elements till it runs out of them.
In the 2-level nested example like below, the first `next` gives us the element from inner most yield, which is 1, the next yields just returns `None`, since it has no elements to return, if you call `next` again, it will return `StopIteration`

```
def mygen():
     yield (yield 1)
a = mygen()
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
```

You can expand this case to include more nested yields, and you will see that after `n` `next` are called, `StopIteration` expection is thrown, below is an example with 5 nested yields

```
def mygen():
     yield ( yield ( yield ( yield (yield 1))))
a = mygen()
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
print(next(a))
```

Note that this answer is just based on my observation, and might not be technically correct in the nitty-gritties, all updates and suggestions are welcome