# Why chaining augmented assignment throws a SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment, increment

Here's the snippet that I'm trying in the Python3 interpreter,

```
>>> x = y = 3
>>> x, y
(3, 3)
>>> x = y = 3
>>> x, y
(3, 3)
>>> x = y = y + 3
>>> x, y
(6, 6)
>>> x = y +=  3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = y +=  3
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that SyntaxError arises when the Python grammar doesn't support the expression, but I'm not able to figure out why exactly `+=` can't be chained like `=`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the python docs -

> With the exception of assigning to tuples and multiple targets in a
>   single statement, the assignment done by augmented assignment
>   statements is handled the same way as normal assignments.

Also,

> the actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than
>   creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object
>   is modified instead.

In python, assignment and augmented assignment are statements, not expressions, and thus cannot be used in complex expressions. For example, the following is valid C, but not valid in Python:

```
a += b += c
```

References:

- [Python Docs - Augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)
- [Wikipedia - Augmented assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment)
- [What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4728073/6042824)