# One liner for dictionary comparison in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the one liner for the below code?

```
for k,v in d2.items():
    if d1.get(k,0) < v:
        return False
return True
```

I tried this but it's invalid syntax.

```
return False if d1.get(k,0)<v for k,v in d2.items() else True
```

Why?

Comment: Take a look at [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#all)

Comment: Are these dicts keeping track of counts of things? You might want to look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Why must this be a one-liner?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, already implemented it and thus the two dicts, unfortunately it doesn't have suitable methods to do what I want which is compare them by value

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga to impress my boss of course! jk, just academically curious :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## TL;DR

#### Most efficient

Use [wjandrea solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605444/12692806)

#### (It is not memory efficient) Not good looking

```py
return False if [True for k, v in d2.items() if d1.get(k, 0) < v] else True
```

#### (It is not memory efficient) Better

```py
return not [True for k, v in d2.items() if d1.get(k, 0) < v]
```

## Explanation

Your code is not syntactically correct because [the `return` **statement**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return-stmt) needs one or more [**expressions**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html).
So, [the `for` **statement**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) is [**not an expression**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) and that's why it fails.

In the code above I wrote a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension), which is an expression, because at the end it is a list.

Then, I make an `if` to the list (which in fact checks the **length** of the list, and if it is empty it will be a **0**, which is **considered False**, while **any other number** is **considered True**).

The second code, which does not have the `if` statement, has the `not` operator, which does the check described earlier with the `if` and then returns a boolean.

I hope this explains *why* that happened, which was your second question.

And also, this post is responding to your main question and not asking why you want it to be one liner. I would prefer to use the multiline version you posted, so you don't store any values and break instantly.

#### EDIT

> I would prefer to use the multiline version you posted, so you don't store any values and break instantly.

Reading [wjandrea correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605444/12692806), I correct myself, with `any` you don't have to store any value, it returns `True` immediately after it finds a `True` value, so it is as efficient as the multiline version.

Comment: This fails to short-circuit, builds a big unnecessary list, and is less clear than using `any` or `all`.

Comment: I like your explanation, but some details are off: 1) `for` in this context makes a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comp-for), not a statement, but yes it's not an expression. 2) `if` in this context makes a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-conditional-expression) (AKA ternary), not a statement. 3) Using `if` on a list is more like `bool(list)` than `bool(len(list))`, since empty lists are falsy themselves, and this is abstracted away to an extent, but yes they're equivalent.

Comment: Yes [user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605333/one-liner-for-dictionary-comparison-in-python/62605730#comment110714872_62605730) you are right, that's why I pointed the [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605444/12692806) solution to be more efficient than mine. I agree that the use of `any` or `all` is more clear.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
return not any(d1.get(k, 0) < v for k, v in d2.items())
```

or

```
return all(d1.get(k, 0) >= v for k, v in d2.items())
```

Comment: Any reason to prefer `not any` to `all`?

Comment: @Nick Yes, using `not any` means we don't have to change the comparison inside the loop, so it's less to think about. But I added an `all` version.

Comment: Good point. Already upvoted so can't do it again...

Answer (score 1):

```
return False if any([d1.get(k,0)<v for k,v in d2.items()]) else True
```

Comment: This technically works, but it's much more verbose than necessary and fails to short-circuit.

Comment: The list is unnecessary and worsens the performance. Also the ternary statement is pointless when you could just use `not`. `return not any(d1.get(k, 0) < v for k, v in d2.items())`

Comment: Sadly yes,  It does not do early termination. I'm wondering is there any better one liner here.

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension, use a generator expression, `any` does short circuit, but that's defeated if you create the whole list up front