# Why can't we use "pass" in a ternary statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator

Here's something simple I thought I would get away with:

```
foo = True
print('bar') if foo else pass
```

Which produces:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Of course I can just replace `pass` with `None` and it will work. I'm just curious: Why doesn't pass work?

Comment: It's not a ternary statement. It's a ternary *expression*. It chooses between *expressions*, not statements, and `pass` isn't an expression.

Comment: `pass` isn't a variable, it's a statement.  You can't use any statements in an if-else expression.  You can only use expressions.  In Python 3, `print` is a function, and calling it is an expression.

Comment: Use the ternary statement to chose between two different values, not actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pass` is a statement and not an expression.

An expression can be used just about anywhere.

Most statements have their special syntax, usually on a line of their own.

For more information about the difference between the two, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a line, as else did nothing, no need of else block.

```
foo = True
if foo : print('bar')
```