# Python Function - Dictionary as Input - Return Error - Interesting Behavior

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, return

Good day, brilliant Stack Overflow Community. I noticed an interesting behavior regarding Python function when input as a dictionary.

When we use the empty list as a default argument, we can return that list while appending some value.

```
def func_list(value,input=[]):
    return input.append(value)
```

I would expect the same thing to apply when empty dictionary as an argument. such as:

```
def func_dict(value,input={}):
    return input[value] = value
```

However, Python will raise a Syntax Error, and I can only do something like:

```
def func_dict(value,input={}):
    input[value] = value
    return input
```

I am wondering why? Thank you so much!

PS. Please feel free to modify the question, and apologize if my expression of the question is not clear enough!

Comment: You can't use "=" in return. The list will also raise an exception in this case: 
def func_list(value,input=[]):
    return input[0] = value

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Indeed input[value] = xxx in this case is a statement. and Python cannot return a statement. like @vaizki suggested!

Comment: As a side note, Python now has assignment expressions via `:=` "walrus" operator. So you can turn many assignment statements into expressions but there is no walrus assignment syntax for `dict` (at least not yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference is that `input.append(value)` is an expression and `input[value] = value` is not (it is just a statement). The `return` statement can only take an expression as a parameter (or no parameters to return None).

You CAN do this:

```
def func_dict(value,input={}):
    return input.update({ value: value }) or input
```

How this works is that `dict.update()` returns None so we return the (now updated) `input` instead. I know it's ugly but can't think of a better one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer! it immediately clarified my confusion!

Comment: For people who stumble upon this post in the future, here is a great summary of what is the difference between a statement and an expression like @vaizki mentioned.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the fact that expressions are also statements but return needs an expression.

Answer (score 0):

On another note, the word `input` is a protected word in python and is used for interactions with the user, you may want to use another parametername as you override the default function when using it the way you do right now.

Here's the documentation regarding input:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Ahh! I see. You are right, input indeed is a bad argument name to use! Thank you so much for pointing out my error!