# How to transform loop below in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to transform loop below in list comprehension? I know this way is more readable, but anyway just wondering..

```
new_dict = {"Water Lilly": "flower",
               "Swifts": "bird",
               "Callery Pear": "tree",
               "Swallows": "bird",
               "Dahlia": "flower",
               "Tulip": "flower",}

for key, value in new_dict.items():
    print(key+':')
    for val in value:
        print("-" + val)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work but kinda hard to read :D

```
x = [(print(key + ":"), [print("-" + val) for val in value]) for key, value in new_dict.items()]
```

It works like a normal listcomprehension

```
[do_sth_with_x(x) for x in list]
```

but your working 2 values

```
[(do_sth_with_x(x), do_sth_with_y(y)) for x, y in list]
```

and in the 3th step you add a second list comprehension instead of the do_st_with_y()

there you go there is your listcomp

Comment: Yea, It works. Looks crazy, but works. Thanks

Comment: You really should not use list-comprehensions purely for side-effects, like printing.

Comment: @PaulM. yeah thats true

Comment: Yea, It was exam task. In the end I submit it yesterday on my way, but still wondering if can be done with other way.

Comment: If you want output as List of dictionaries - ```lst = [ {k: v} for k, v in new_dict.items()]``` ,  if you wanted output as List of lists ```lst = [ [k, v] for k, v in new_dict.items()]``` and then ```print(lst)```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a one-liner as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71202112/1274195). We can agree that the one liner is hard to read. Another issue with it is that we are using side-effects in the comprehension, which is generally considered a bad practice as well.

List comprehensions are expressions; something that evaluates to a value. As opposed to statements, something that is an imperative directive to the interpreter. `print(..)` statements are, well, statements. Take a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) question to learn about the differences.

Purely as an exercise of converting a nested for loop into list comprehension, we can try and tackle this problem from the inside out.

let's start with a simple example.

```
for i in list1:
   do_something(i)
```

can be converted to `[do_something(i) for i in list1`]

but if we have multiple statements, how do we get all of them to execute?

```
for i in list1:
   do_something(i)
   do_something_else(i)
```

we can use a "trick" of python where a tuple is evaluated in order whenever python encounters it.

`[(do_something(i), do_something_else(i)) for i in list1]`

```
for key, value in new_dict.items():
    do_outer(key)
    for val in value:
        do_inner(value)
```

converting the inner loop to List comprehension looks like this

```
for key, value in new_dict.items():
    do_outer(key)
    [do_inner(value) for value in value]
```

next we can try to convert the outer loop

`[(inner loop stuff) for key, value in new_dict.items()]`

expanding the inner loop stuff

```
[(do_outer(key), [do_inner(value) for value in value]) for
                      key, value in new_dict.items()]
```

We use the tuple trick to club both `do_outer` and the inner comprehension inside the outer comprehension.

I think we can all agree that the for loop is simpler to read and understand, and looking at the list comprehension, we have no idea what kind of crazy side-effects `do_inner` and `do_outer` may cause.