# Why aren't these two ternary expressions equal?

Tags: python, conditional-operator, in-place

When I run the below code, I get two different values for i. Why?

The only difference is the first uses `i = i + 1` whereas the second uses `i += 1` which are equivalent in all other use cases I've seen.

```
i = 1
k = 2
i = i + 1 if i == k else k
print(i) # prints 2

i = 1
k = 2
i += 1 if i == k else k

print(i) # prints 3
```

Comment: `i += 1` is not an expression. You have `i += (1 if ...)`.

Comment: What you have have typed is parsed as `i += (1 if i == k else k)` so i is incremented by 2.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні The duplicates are not related to this question. The examples in this question are valid ternary operations. They just give different results while the ones in the duplicate question are syntax errors.

Comment: @Selcuk they are not 100% duplicates but they explain OP's core confusion: that there's no way that += is inside the first branch of the conditional expression. Your answer clarifies nothing in this regard.

Comment: @Selcuk I was wrong, sorry. OP's confusion is even simpler. I think your answer would benefit from spelling out both complete statements with superfluous parentheses.

Comment: @Selcuk how about the new dupe?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Yes, that's an exact duplicate. Also updated my answer per your suggestion.

Comment: Also see: [What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python) When you use `+=` it is part of a statement where the value is the entire RHS. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Answer (score 2):

According to [Python's operator precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), in the first example the ternary expression applies to `i + 1`. So the following

```
i = i + 1 if i == k else k
```

is equivalent to

```
i = ((i + 1) if i == k else k)
```

Whereas the following

```
i += 1 if i == k else k
```

is equivalent to

```
i += (1 if i == k else k)
```