# Assign value in ternary operator

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

When using `std::weak_ptr`, it is best practice to access the corresponding `std::shared_ptr` with the `lock()` method, as so:

```cpp
std::weak_ptr<std::string> w;
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s = std::make_shared<std::string>("test");

w = s;

if (auto p = w.lock())
   std::cout << *p << "\n";
else
   std::cout << "Empty";
```

If I wanted to use the ternary operator to short hand this, it would seem that this:

```cpp
std::cout << (auto p = w.lock()) ? *p : "Empty";
```

would be valid code, but this does not compile.

Is it possible to use this approach with the ternary operator?

Comment: All parts of a conditional expression are in turn expressions. You can't have definition of variables in expressions.

Comment: Somewhat related: [what's an expression and expression statement in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7479946/11082165) and [Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19132/11082165). Declarations are not expressions in C++, so it won't be possible to declare `p` inside of the first expression of `?:`. However, _assignments_ are expressions, so something like `(p = w.lock()) ? *p : "Empty"` would be valid, assuming `p` was already declared.

Comment: You could declare `p` outside the ternary and then assign it inside, but then you can't use the placeholder `auto`.  It'd be `std::shared_ptr<std::string> p; std::cout << (p = w.lock()) ? *p : "Empty";`

Comment: @NateEldredge you might not be able to use `auto` in that case, but you can still deduce the `shared_ptr` type from the `weak_ptr`, by using `std::shared_ptr<decltype(w)::element_type> p;`, or even simpler `decltype(w.lock()) p;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto p = w.lock()` is not an assignment. It's a declaration of a variable. You can declare a variable in the condition of an `if` statement, but you cannot declare variables within a conditional expression.

You can write:

```
auto p = w.lock();
std::cout << (
    p ? *p
      : "Empty"
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to introduce a variable for an expression (like `let` in Lisp or Haskell), you can use a **lambda**:

```
std::cout << [p = w.lock()] {return p ? *p : "Empty";}();
```

This also confines the `?:`, which interprets `std::cout` as part of the *condition* in your question.