# Language concepts about expression and statement

Tags: programming-languages

Any computer language have 'expression' and 'statement'. in concept, what's the diff?

Comment: The key thing is that statements are not allowed in expression contexts. And note that not all languages have statements.

Comment: I don't understand why so much people around here answer questions in comments instead of as...answers.

Comment: @Klaim maybe because it's harder to downvote a comment :)

Comment: Pay close attention to what @DanD. wrote: not every computer language has expressions and statements. For instance, pure functional languages do not have statements and [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk) does not have neither statements nor expressions (only commands) while being (mostly) imperative.

Comment: @Klaim, that's because sometimes an answer does not answer exactly what was asked: pointing out a problem with the statement made in a question (pun intended) is one such example ;-)

Comment: @Klaim Well, If you consider what I say to be an answer, I may not, and so I leave it to you to do what you will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29#Expressions) :

> In most languages, statements contrast with expressions in that
>   statements do not return results and are executed solely for their
>   side effects, while expressions always return a result and often do
>   not have side effects at all. Among imperative programming languages,
>   Algol 68 is one of the few in which a statement can return a result.
>   In languages which mix imperative and functional styles, such as the
>   Lisp family, the distinction between expressions and statements is not
>   made: even expressions executed in sequential contexts solely for
>   their side effects and whose return values are not used are considered
>   'expressions'. In purely functional programming, there are no
>   statements; everything is an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions have a value, while statements do not. If you can pass it as an argument to a function, it's an expression. If you can't, it's a statement. Control flow constructs in C-derived languages are generally statements (you can't pass an 'if {}' block as a function parameter). Consequently, those languages tend to provide an expression form for 'if' (like the ternary operator). Of course, the whole point of many functional languages is that everything has a value, and that functions are first-class values, which means that everything is an expression. Statements usually appear in imperative languages, where you wish to write commands that don't necessarily return a value.For Details see a link.
http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1044
 And This Question of StackOverflow also help you.
[Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement)

Answer (score 0):

`statements` typically do not have a value. `expressions` typically do have a value.

This is often visible in languages such as Ruby or Erlang that provide an value to something such as `if .. end` constructs:

```ruby
> foo = if 1 then "hello" else "goodbye" end
=> "hello"
> foo
=> "hello"
```

```erlang
1> Foo = if 1 =:= 1 ->
1>   hello;
1> true ->
1>   goodbye
1> end.
hello
2>
```

Many languages will not allow you to use `lvalue = if ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Language's "statements" are actually instructions for computer system to do something.

Language's "expressions" are combination of operators and operands like z=x+y. Roughly I can say that the language expressions are mathematical in nature.

Every language's "expression" is a language's "statement" but every language's "statement" is not a language's "expression".

Comment: It's not necessarily true that statements are a subset of expressions; you could imagine a language where just writing `a + b` is illegal without saying `c = a + b`.