# Initialization variable inside if

Tags: c#, variables, initialization

Hi we can not define in c# variable like this

```
if((var input = db.table.FirstOrDefault()) != null)
{
   // and here I could use my 'input' variable
}
```

but i can do it this way

```
for(var input = db.table.FirstOrDefault(); input != null; input = null)
{
  //opeartion

}
```

Can anyone tell me why? Woudn't that be nice if we could do it using if ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? `for()` is used for looping, these two snippets of code are completly different

Comment: @Shai I won't, i wish to be able to use first solution, second is only to show that this is possible in short way.

Comment: You can't do it because C# doesn't let you. *Why* C# doesn't let you is a *subjective* questionthat only the people who designed C# can answer (but most likely is because "its confusing and not all that useful")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because writing

```
object input = db.table.FirstOrDefault();
```

is exactly the same like writing

```
object input; 
input = db.table.FirstOrDefault();
```

accoring to the C# specification.

This means that *there is no any  return value*, so there is nothing to check `!=null` against.

Yes, I think it's possible to trick this, to make some changes in compiler, but probabbly it doesn't worth effort.

Answer (score 2):

Because that leads to long-known hard-to-track errors:

```
if (var t = true) {}

bool t;
if (t = true) {}

bool t;
if (t == true) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

As to the why, it's because `input = db.table.FirstOrDefault()` is a **statement** and doesn't actually return anything. It **assigns** something to the `input` variable. As it doesn't return anything (i.e. it's a statement), you cannot compare it to something else.

The `if` expects an **expression** (something that **returns** something). Here's more on [the difference between statements and expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement).

This is different from C where (if I'm not mistaken) everything that has a value of 0 if `false` and everything else is `true`.

As to the closest you can get with C#, I believe you can do something like:

```
MyClass input = null;
if ((input = db.table.FirstOrDefault()) != null)
{
    // use input here
}
```

But then you might as well do:

```
MyClass input = db.table.FirstOrDefault();
if (input != null)
{
    // use input here
}
```

Comment: off course i know i can do it this way, I was just wondering if this idea is worth to think to implement.

Comment: Just being complete (hey, other, less experienced developers might land on this page). The question (the why) is answered in the first part of my answer (difference between statements and expressions in C#).

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop you define index variables for iteration. You could write it like that:

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < x; ++i)
{
    // Some code;
}
```

But in that case the `i` variable would exist outside of the iteration, so `for` loop creates variable with a scope of the iteration. In an `if` you don't need additional variables for it to work.