# Pandas DF eval failing if it's not explicit

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column named `foo` contianing booleans, True or False, and I want to understand why:

```
df.eval("foo")  -> fails with ValueError: unknown type object
df.eval("foo == True")  -> works
```

It seems like this first line should select the `True` value as well.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4725, in eval
    return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs)
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/eval.py", line 357, in eval
    ret = eng_inst.evaluate()
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/engines.py", line 81, in evaluate
    res = self._evaluate()
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/engines.py", line 121, in _evaluate
    return ne.evaluate(s, local_dict=scope)
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py", line 975, in evaluate
    raise e
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py", line 877, in validate
    signature = [(name, getType(arg)) for (name, arg) in
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py", line 877, in <listcomp>
    signature = [(name, getType(arg)) for (name, arg) in
  File "/home/scheltie/pyvenv/mscheltienne/eeg-flow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py", line 717, in getType
    raise ValueError("unknown type %s" % a.dtype.name)
ValueError: unknown type object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your problem, with a random initialization:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

choices = [True, False]
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': np.random.choice(choices, 10)})
```

Both of the statements work and return the same series

```
df.eval("foo")
df.eval("foo == True")
```

But if you initialized with string "True" instead of Boolean, like below, you get the same error you mentioned in your code `ValueError: unknown type object`

```
choices = ["True", "False"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': np.random.choice(choices, 10)})
```

So I assume your "foo" column is object/string instead of bool. Converting it using either `map` or `apply` to a boolean series first should fix your problem

```
df['foo'] = df['foo'].apply(eval)
```

Comment: It is indeed `object` even if I don't see any init with a str, but indeed with `True` / `False`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to Python documentation, in [pandas.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) the attribute "expr" cannot contain any Python statements, only Python expressions.
The function evaluates a Python expression as a string using various backends.

The differences between Statements and Expression you can read here [1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600891/19385098) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32343866/19385098).