# Why is Python's eval() rejecting this multiline string, and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, eval

I am attempting to eval the following tab-indented string:

```
'''for index in range(10):
        os.system("echo " + str(index) + "")
'''
```

I get, "There was an error: invalid syntax , line 1"

What is it complaining about? Do I need to indent to match the eval() statement, or write it to a string file or temp file and execute that, or something else?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`eval` evaluates stuff like `5+3`

`exec` executes stuff like `for ...`

```
>>> eval("for x in range(3):print x")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    for x in range(3):print x
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> exec("for x in range(3):print x")
0
1
2
>>> eval('5+3')
8
```

Comment: Oops. Your answer was here! Should have marked that as dupe :P

Comment: I caught this from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671563/eval-not-working-on-multi-line-string#comment49405263_30671563 :D

Answer (score 17):

To use such statements with `eval` you should convert them to code object first, using [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile):

```
In [149]: import os

In [150]: cc = compile('''for index in range(10):
    os.system("echo " + str(index) + "")''','<string>','single')

In [154]: eval cc
--------> eval(cc)
0
Out[154]: 0
1
Out[154]: 0
2
Out[154]: 0
3
Out[154]: 0
4

In [159]: cc = compile("2+2", '<string>', 'single')  # works with simple expressions too 

In [160]: eval cc
--------> eval(cc)
Out[160]: 4
```

Answer (score 7):

We evaluate ([`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)) expressions, and execute ([`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec)) statements.

*See: [Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement).*

> Expression: Something which evaluates to a value. Example: 1+2/x
>   Statement: A line of code which does something. Example: GOTO 100

Answer (score 6):

**(See default security warning at end before you put code like this into production!)**

The other answers do a good job of explaining the difference between `exec` and `eval`.

Nevertheless, I found myself wanting to take input like `x=1; y=2; x+y` rather than force people to write:

```
def f():
   x = 1
   y = 2
   return x + y
```

String manipulation of code to build this sort of function is a risky business.

I ended up using the following approach:

```
def multiline_eval(expr, context):
    "Evaluate several lines of input, returning the result of the last line"
    tree = ast.parse(expr)
    eval_expr = ast.Expression(tree.body[-1].value)
    exec_expr = ast.Module(tree.body[:-1])
    exec(compile(exec_expr, 'file', 'exec'), context)
    return eval(compile(eval_expr, 'file', 'eval'), context)
```

This parses python code; uses the ast library to rebuild an ast of everything apart from the last line; and the last line, execing the former and eval'ing the later.

## Security warning

This is the obligatory security warning that you have to attach to `eval`.
`Eval`'ing and `exec`'ing code that is provided by a non-privileged user is of course insecure. In these cases you may prefer to use another approach, or consider ast.literal_eval. `eval` and and `exec` tend to be bad ideas unless you actually want to give your user the full expressive power of python.

Answer (score 1):

A better version.

```
def multiline_eval(expr, context={}):
    "Evaluate several lines of input, returning the result of the last line"
    tree = ast.parse(expr)
    eval_exprs = []
    exec_exprs = []
    for module in tree.body:
        if isinstance(module, ast.Expr):
            eval_exprs.append(module.value)
        else:
            exec_exprs.append(module)
    exec_expr = ast.Module(exec_exprs, type_ignores=[])
    exec(compile(exec_expr, 'file', 'exec'), context)
    results = []
    for eval_expr in eval_exprs:
        results.append(eval(compile(ast.Expression((eval_expr)), 'file', 'eval'), context))
    return '\n'.join([str(r) for r in results])
```

So you can run code in [Qt](https://gist.github.com/eccstartup/efb98af84616006981ba8b1527eaf1ba).